Could checksums be provided for the July 2024+/"new" SE-hosted data dumps?
One of the nice things with the previous "torrent"-based downloads of the dump, and some of the internet archive front ends was that there were built in ways to verify that a download was correct.
While I'm planning on generating checksums for the dumps I can obtain (and am requesting a full set for this purpose) - as a means of verifying older dumps - for someone downloading a single dump, this is a little excessive.
I feel that having a way to check if a specific download's correct seems to be a good idea. I do realise a historic archive of these is out of scope (and the community ought to be able to generate these if need be), but having a checksum provided with the download given by the 'new' dump download option would be nice.

Automatically, but its a nice to have! My next question would explain why :D

I've downloaded the entire thing (all sites), but I have no way to check if it was correctly downloaded. With archive.org, this was automatically managed by the torrent. Torrents split up the files and download them in smaller pieces, and have built-in error handling to account for that. Instead, I have had to download the entire stackoverflow.com.7z archive thrice (including an ongoing download) because of download errors. That's 63.7GiB three times. But hey, maybe excess bandwidth use gets SE to realise torrents are actually a much better distribution method

From information that others have provided, it appears that the data dumps are uploaded to Cloudflare R2 using 100MB chunks (not MiB), and R2 uses S3-compatible ETag headers, so the ETag header on a download will be equal to md5(concatenation of md5(chunk) for each 100MB chunk) + "-" + ceil(size / 1000MB). This isn't as convenient to verify as if it were using a normal hash algorithm directly, but it's not too complicated. This could make a good semi-official hash.

This is a community-compiled SHA256 checksum list. This is not a good replacement for a built-in checksum feature, but exists as a best effort until we get a proper checksum feature.
The list is generated by having two people download the entire data dump, generate checksums, and check if they match. If any files have a SHA256 mismatch, both people redownload the mismatched files, and regenerate the checksum for those specific files. Rinse and repeat if necessary until everything matches.
For the June 2024 data dump, it was verified that the archives do not have any form of fingerprinting, which makes it fairly straight-forward to generate the checksums.
The reason this isn't optimal is that if two people download the same file with the exact same damage, the checksums will still match. Normally, this has an effectively 0% chance of happening if we assume the source download is perfect. But if, for example, the download process is borked on SE's side, this could result in bad downloads with the exact same type of error. That's why this list is not a substitute for official checksum; the process used to generate it is flawed, and cannot be fully fixed. If anything breaks on SE's side for everyone at the time of generation, this process (and the resulting checksums) will not be able to tell.
In theory, because 7z files use a solid compression format, the entire thing should break if any of the content breaks, which means that additionally running:
#!/usr/bin/bash
for filename in *.7z; do
    7z l "$filename" > /dev/null || echo "$filename is bad"
done

Should be able to tell if any of the archives are borked at the source when all the checksums line up. I'm not sure if this is a correct assumption; feel free to correct this part.

The reason this list exists anyway is that this may be the only option we have for at least several months. I hope this answer becomes unnecessary fast, but until then, it's the best we got.
Until a better solution is found, this answer's revisions will contain the historical checksums and try to keep up with new data dumps, starting with the June 2024 data dump.
June 2024 (original)
$ sha256sum *.7z

a48a9e6b5756b6acdb5728478246b612263a578a8fbaa0d852e2bd0dd5e6f7ff  3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
826b16125035a53e4a0c339459a42a8aba88fb3d7b0c930212afaa0d811ce4b6  3dprinting.stackexchange.com.7z
fa54ebb9f5c3083509e037ef07348f25e4ef335dc21e23b31e496ec7ac212e0b  academia.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
85e1ccd6a3744231616ff2a58780dec248c11fed33850b8a3dce49279c629b2f  academia.stackexchange.com.7z
e65da5783d44747f596abc37b6b80c670ed1c563f765e8a4a4cb694acff82980  ai.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4ddb0d26bfa04a26e3b5692bc6066bb4732431ad0ee10f80f134ad316003a06b  ai.stackexchange.com.7z
2bf4d0a8baf8cb09fd3f12e4a43ed72e0b02cd931781ab144a24ef61c69f45b8  android.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
396d763a1133f47f1259b5156e6fe7e6fa0711746a00441d88d391a32df94c56  android.stackexchange.com.7z
14ba3c7502810c6b4c34f223020a389c8b0a6f3d7da981bac37c63a7790adda4  anime.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1cfd9c5b78ecb277e98bdf43ecfad272a42846546dff1c19a285bd9af5b4f7a9  anime.stackexchange.com.7z
c16842a40dca68ae138f8b0975e1125f17abec08acc3c5b94790ede889ba2707  apple.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
fb6be1dda0526b925996387689257ed18014974b2928ddcc5dc7ca462dd744a3  apple.stackexchange.com.7z
885e43757dc67e9018836823e9c9515d83b073696c7da872482e78e8a9e961f6  arduino.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3eb63e3db66be16451c40a5ba19060fc49992e5a659693aa91983508473d8185  arduino.stackexchange.com.7z
79593631660efab2163c5a91e1b8fbda12b156a89359a334d24de0b7c6292a9c  askubuntu.com.7z
8ea637005076b0336c07f42e3722423aec9453856eb5bd1883dba30b0265b0fc  astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
25fe5b460e125db30235e3d929b69d780eac32b01b0885c6783cb4c0beb79eff  astronomy.stackexchange.com.7z
b390b9d15dac7d5cff4613315203055b1cb8160076befccebd00461263d09ca3  aviation.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
bab826100dc3c29c8d2665297effaa0c327a63103acd69bd505726d6ce05cf1f  aviation.stackexchange.com.7z
fbfc077d9fcd06cf9ee15985e3a87158e50ffb3c53fe4b632f557d2fc83b358f  avp.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
273ad6faa3973635f6ec2239f8dc743e35bf3550d9e904be79e9aa18bef7dc50  avp.stackexchange.com.7z
3d2bc1285c221cc4d808ed5de722f6432feb32f60a9b20cb54e0c78c2e2ed2f0  beer.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
6d3f5cf66960e4d89f66cda30316319fad8c5f790956674fc52221520f7f0e86  beer.stackexchange.com.7z
c8400663b4e2056d3fbfd209014b456c9211ed2e4708eef676df8f8062edda97  bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
6cd804887c196f8b47af420c28357116a5044fa7321f121730e33aaa70d8c99f  bicycles.stackexchange.com.7z
8fac7e92da19e85d9790a760888c0e7011911ac14659ebcfdbb22e5f576ad57c  bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
dd1994517ddc9533c36bdfe90b09f8232df208a7a0a8ace50769dc8fecec06e7  bioacoustics.stackexchange.com.7z
6cc488720b1e25c2a830322abff14a1ad6480807637b9b3854ecec47ff710269  bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
36f9ca77a9116b1cd8921f6bf1a6a27389e4880d22760045717eacec2c90c00c  bioinformatics.stackexchange.com.7z
f175e249993690480b5a1d48aaab20cd54a5fd3bd31bde583c9b21a5e703e351  biology.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1676b3016f54cf23c6c743b84c887cf85dc232c77ddce4559d19a202d62b7850  biology.stackexchange.com.7z
75f7f051bf9fa12bbf8adafffcc8ae070c5b82fb618b3ccc5d705bfe7000e463  bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
7e2fbfaf560ee8179431095a3252a51fec976b3b8b99bad08f154d2d5b3303b7  bitcoin.stackexchange.com.7z
192fd0ab8d3a19af6ddc39563325afba7386c03a2e1b9424a04025d748b1d6a6  blender.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
fa282833842e77efd4283e352e0afba28abd01c10ed02e2788f91b079b6cc32f  blender.stackexchange.com.7z
ef09c664ad58169336edf71506f9b71cc1a7f1af692c9987cc42ae185a054739  boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
811973e28027da3ab335af7b956bac1713a13d2a728755ecbc6e0008ee9d9bba  boardgames.stackexchange.com.7z
703715d1ede98f07a1630c6859b96adf0033d05684a72d7f2ece076b26deccf6  bricks.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
aa68ea657f563a4ced633f35af0e377564114a5ab0a5718d8886c01025d619fb  bricks.stackexchange.com.7z
b6320e34dab8886e6886248db6445126760fb60650d04821ca870f2471a65bdb  buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
e939f5ad23008abee8a1eaed7157f7ccadbcc43e28bc66ecc6b062ba50abca5f  buddhism.stackexchange.com.7z
389e5ec2ad26f9c7795c8f70337dc76b8b5f954a2ee201133d0e3c688b9ba83d  cardano.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
2786f126adabf9660362c967649c4e24692786788fda5e7a115cff71eed73b92  cardano.stackexchange.com.7z
0d528b01ff9bcfb2561a285da94be79ec364f5b9a954052549159e30714db203  chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
73d9c7c339f4c4c7a6c08f21679d63aadf7b025ffe346ce77ba816cff0c8ee7d  chemistry.stackexchange.com.7z
0a69304cc0896bbddd17c079491656fe7afb756057922f21d0c67a434623a0d7  chess.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c34756e74d2208964cb09ec58024cbc99fb360f3c60447bdfdab44a10a40a0aa  chess.stackexchange.com.7z
28a886708dea3445464ef16a1629d437e43e3c3651ba4942929cb247d1063f80  chinese.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a2221fa9e26c6464c5dc4f89efaa558c9c33086dd441386c7c62b7fab6e58442  chinese.stackexchange.com.7z
8d544ee26c6a51e917b13d9bff496403fd8644626aab6d3adda08a985a45ec44  christianity.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d6aca3e77cb2bb24a1f591f0d58906f6f2ea44fd52abaf43b56c221911fc3506  christianity.stackexchange.com.7z
545a1086bc1f65a0f7ca3b46e4e63e9131348ea0504a093260065826d3c2895f  civicrm.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1971ef80bb3d9e980f26c8ea2edad32745cd5a5c89d65fc7822ab06744f4ce71  civicrm.stackexchange.com.7z
976f4bda2815fea538e86bcdd6978d9cd05890393bf46cf1bdebd2e46aca9782  codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d4a81b1d5e493f7a4200677d0b7000cbfcba88be8cef9ec6c7b8aa4f5534043a  codegolf.stackexchange.com.7z
8e91a9fbe80c01d7ae1aebc1503da2f34e4e4e850d445e32d0decc9991a20269  codereview.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1067ec59bf311c0d6f3022c6caa2bf34131e83c61cb18204b1501d633544e3af  codereview.stackexchange.com.7z
cffa4b345616d7bcc249882da29645a36b22c826928f39db688ac21af7344403  coffee.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
9cd55678cc33b254f1068cd69dce67b17a3ed53796e997d8a43076694b779e23  coffee.stackexchange.com.7z
804a380c713af9ed559643824323a897305bb1c10d7b64da1f23fb12e6e1fce2  cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1d06d9dd2666281f2a36ea51251580f43ba77288ccbff2dab148987ae620d445  cogsci.stackexchange.com.7z
8e44b95f5d584b6ff9278e9b6de469bfb2e22d12e167a45f3fef5a2ec7dc945e  computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
48d2719a2615b479692c0f994a58ae8a5fe27ea4d1297a901df9fd349898008b  computergraphics.stackexchange.com.7z
30a05c5e6495811db57c3b4f4d5808032dcffcd7fed86e13c90ced8228232a4d  conlang.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c065647a8d4f1bae8b205b4e88c45dcbf3c32e97a1884162dc6576f8ca928374  conlang.stackexchange.com.7z
5e420499034c158423a89dbd43eb94d7b0bc4e08c9addaef5ae79f1d2de34c28  cooking.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
715372cafb886610f088996a610087d8fdf5d1cb38756fe71cf0d9ba5331ac65  cooking.stackexchange.com.7z
ed88ee1cc3716167dccbaaaa84b4b21766a8d9dfa95a79d19ea627cb12e4d18d  craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
7d81ac406ad22670e49a142e1f50727918b589c8f87b822f1d63df5354d55c94  craftcms.stackexchange.com.7z
c81e83b90eb9ff0988d3c8012678f76dd9f355dce2860b85b6d198614eda40a5  crafts.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
9d0a3fac42d7e5ea023fc96d6d5b6e6bf2ce4e4e8e58bfb4191db32c5b65171d  crafts.stackexchange.com.7z
d8c461ad26ffe37d5890dac4af598450b646d54a3e207de3561ae701dc5a7ccb  crypto.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
30f85aa942492edc6a29e6e9ba7f2557190d51a5bef0708d51690b649721a7dd  crypto.stackexchange.com.7z
24a72547c7e559c62efcc8a608779db92e0d247374c9b6f854035a9a0a6390b7  cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
dd932c0b547519496c7c54fc44c03bd7666e0068c06bfe7e21a86f757eb5d85e  cseducators.stackexchange.com.7z
2650fc589e86093d41136b4be1e653a1e5de523fe3d2a89808491037075ff24d  cs.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1f02fa49e6119a959bcdb04b2a29f69ab812a50a8e51a01e2dafa349d8c23c19  cs.stackexchange.com.7z
eef6db6d055b9eb50cceeb04fb6d8a8cc675cc0a484451588aa82fa91e5d793c  cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d9ec0e38553ad5e0e893c1b723ac998e0917d8061cc9591cc2b46f4085099a23  cstheory.stackexchange.com.7z
ea969d3396bc772f1061dffa7b9e55c48bdf0ddaeb92d861201d822384a2824e  datascience.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a81a6f5290b5ea1c2fcee7f06a3534a1cdcc0608d5510c63bce78bdedf6a494b  datascience.stackexchange.com.7z
7827b625a7df24ac890ca01017519169a711a3a999a5e90c736d42e62b9022a7  dba.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b0a6fdb04958d0acc9606da3cb45d028316cdb82530df01fbc581d661a99b024  dba.stackexchange.com.7z
78e8d1d2ab98fa581c564df8ac64661fb5cf28f20e768605aaecd05f8bc85085  devops.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
2796e25257a80b237cf843c96df0878074730cc4babcd6b53f3ce2d4661278c4  devops.stackexchange.com.7z
00bbe2395d0ef40653267af98a08dabb702331b3e557867305bebdec792f2d89  diy.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
0cf1887ef3648ea22f56428af118b131f4a6b51fa0d27de0c97ecaf083e25556  diy.stackexchange.com.7z
f4092319956334476ebc8fef0ce9a680f7bc580a256f5a8d254093431780a7fa  drones.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
82cdfa30a9bb4f7f6d14bda4ed5099725febf34bc060ea1ed4d160a4b751d872  drones.stackexchange.com.7z
8c0113985abe17e3bd92c2281db29743f019405110979da020f511f9d329896c  drupal.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
54358dfdf48390db1387f58a4f967bd928927a0245040cf34d64d6505986eaef  drupal.stackexchange.com.7z
e7c50123997580e00befc79dcd8011219a5d6fa714ff63720099cd6c93805064  dsp.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
462787b626f5dea0f4530d3b6e4435b9ed7615826b247d7f4e290f519ef17a62  dsp.stackexchange.com.7z
a58d864597da6e84459babf4eb74c61488b5d8cb9723c2db18381281dbf5d2e7  earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
39a047fa498d2823c0d580e1b1cc24dd7cf57b6a92e869e6f7392cd7433a5cfa  earthscience.stackexchange.com.7z
2853de442382be9bf3c841365b66a5367bd7f0fa796e812e88eb4b1db57e6c0a  ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c950a4671bbc42efaf53d10eb3a76c3263edae12cfec90f0f7c982b29cbcfec7  ebooks.stackexchange.com.7z
9ff81fea5542c2807704c37da9497ebf7666cd4dff5c0fa7977e3cb6af2f572d  economics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4c66c71a7771b9b3ef11ba1ab2cffa2571969f138598fe425ec80e7c0dfb09fe  economics.stackexchange.com.7z
67d4ffb5bd1ec51657d2ce407c9481d303e9e607a9c8bdd730098459c61f7808  electronics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d05d839bc744a01658abfa78301f12d421f48d51d43f1d7421c9067e0f910cb2  electronics.stackexchange.com.7z
55ec72eacaeeb6aeac33e09c9ad90bffffbd112d6b02dbd04fb0f5bfa510807d  elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
196d9ee58c6fd0c0bae58cd542702f0c891064c17476b3ee91d9297559740fb6  elementaryos.stackexchange.com.7z
cded3c89b58ce8d7e615c9344803df4ccad70a9c961c9f5031a81103d85f41b8  ell.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
23938665229d76da7d72f8d0d470cbd01e4dce04875167a704779d3ef4ac8ca1  ell.stackexchange.com.7z
fff1db330a4500c066631143259479e6798bfb7bbb8d7a9ea7ba02b3ff6fc2fc  emacs.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
6c7bb9142cafa9e67e9714307cd0ea1ad47a06ab5bb1037f5876b0cba6544a46  emacs.stackexchange.com.7z
2b876b4c9bc3f894101fbcc304b5b3f0e4af0db201332e82747492c2e49f7e81  engineering.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
afcb3421e4c1a10f1d328b64b46b7fb8c742919d17d6a08aed65ffa795d4fbae  engineering.stackexchange.com.7z
ced728758ff4b1c936712afa53ba43dc2c97567cda233e6dac1bd58b74e858af  english.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
e3d391f7a8bd841c75575ce4795be2d0aa7e49a0f4b2c77d99d26e03c340199b  english.stackexchange.com.7z
4b233899c0e6969baa77d56b7dffde757152c36d2ff0c11987dedc261996f39d  eosio.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
62bc0c26c2a2cd364934dd23a5a2f987b10dbff8bcb9e4f5fde32ca9522a535f  eosio.stackexchange.com.7z
68c8ce3e06ae8c9bd17fa24a9cef9a32bec4cc39a19987aec64bc5acb83e4575  es.meta.stackoverflow.com.7z
2432d0201f35a4b8fd5fe642924a33e8b6f36d59c839fc4d36264f82f1e91d46  esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
113f738a7dc2f50062296a105453ffa09386d9e0647b08288a81baf6a984b021  esperanto.stackexchange.com.7z
f5d05d728ffb2969424ad88be15c3ae9574656c3120d0446a8738bceb4b66d26  es.stackoverflow.com.7z
f98f5336be76070ec749dded63b342eff020ddfe0ee49ec8589643aae921b0c9  ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1bf1ff8b25141eb0b8ee07dc23ad34948406957f4360c40473de722d0da629b7  ethereum.stackexchange.com.7z
d26797c0adc553e8e14166fa36dedfbab77dbfeb5c077b55e2a0d15562c1c29d  expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
9b0db789af6b87a75bc60441ff0819271e06a079fa10051cd0659d3eb115faee  expatriates.stackexchange.com.7z
60c795c9d4fe0f0dcf97b61deb8d34e8ec4bc3ed568fa0b9d8fb36ac82b01e8a  expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
e2415b55c38955a007f33f18b1578e0e537226fce707588d1af239363ba2a940  expressionengine.stackexchange.com.7z
1676287bafdc5e7f6a5f53a75dc10aacb5d36ce27adb69cdbbd42e95b325095a  fitness.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3128e5e7cb76ca66ec20bf7c6a3bf16b037d8044ee7688f21514f98d048e1f5b  fitness.stackexchange.com.7z
093cbbf60297d0fe2ca83c942a27ae24626c59032a5095ccb596b8b953639711  freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
dd3c4f0615cf2179faca14f924b978025bb8a2410d4b7ff2ed289f439ac0381a  freelancing.stackexchange.com.7z
b77ff1f2a0d9785c08c7adec2d06390d49b190599fd9d4c7ce6374cae24e93da  french.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
98374228170a3617eea23c73b98dd81e343264b64defddefa9228d05b42f0da4  french.stackexchange.com.7z
d0cf556c7fb584fa9ebab95a45f08cdf044b5d564ea1ef5223d130e28f982adc  gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b87a739190f4e143d5edf12eac931bda60fdb8301489ae2976e1a930091a905a  gamedev.stackexchange.com.7z
2d988aa2f8d229768be107881b9b8b470575751b784eeb396157647e0394f13f  gaming.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
fa4a7f1678c13eb2773dba0a370a77b371a2fa335f2e36b8d6af4cf8349d714b  gaming.stackexchange.com.7z
12324f36e33811819b8b15fbe28035593402dcd273d151306c78ef380ad99caa  gardening.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d7eb1b003084ed2ea6e04d499df224c1109daf7e23f8e97a06008c01eaef1a2a  gardening.stackexchange.com.7z
1167c308c6886aedccabc292700bba0e9d23008fcb0f0296fbb4e79adcae8a1d  genai.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a6809b6d8d806dd5abfe2dbbf86d14a7f9d71067b2e60bec3c11018710df3ac7  genai.stackexchange.com.7z
8018721df8eab48b6bc0c5d191bbdb04bcb13afba3e97a3ca7f0ab0a38fa86df  genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c5c51d80036c5601f5fc878412c9e6a1e7abf8c68616e394eb51472fe8fbb733  genealogy.stackexchange.com.7z
268ff7cee7e5a659c72cec8acf88bbbaec64d352cfb0b441102cce174d620725  german.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
881f73c79a745db59c638c66084f8f7064ae1c5f6d6259b6845e9e8af3caf95c  german.stackexchange.com.7z
d9f11b80c267644c776f6c45ba35fe425027e3fa2f07aa97be219c7a47e016cf  gis.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
6995a4b051a59586d297e218b8827575699960db7303801ab493db7602b7a132  gis.stackexchange.com.7z
774132253909d3463a579cbec8eef5a77f5d2618e6075526a711b069f9c06420  graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ddedc45f0e0917339ebc7f74b98b650615cffad0ed9708f70592129c8e537bf1  graphicdesign.stackexchange.com.7z
33c6d9c3e483272eb5adde087eda54fb7da90316dff3c1b791b7d7d993e4328b  ham.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d5a714d229fda5b280f90b18c1f48bd6051bc05d4cd9b559482243db197fdf28  ham.stackexchange.com.7z
764222ac7b000485ac32cba2323c8e0cac5fb0fd380b3c38c922afba587e98ab  hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
078c2942d00008c71034f05ebf6a3248681f8cd53733662c61630c4c5ea582ab  hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com.7z
1b612200b15f135b0383e7f9e64dd8490a790e1fec633f052c1a8197d996505a  health.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
43df2c60d0038f9fc9eb9c41aeaf19dbd48004e607c26b6daf614a840cfc0b0f  health.stackexchange.com.7z
3f2d499b752ee0159318af3821cca3eda0cd8be14ae59538e0703938b2f0082f  hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
9e05235d28686ace1ba1bee49319a84ade421784e9eb027499f26dca24937b86  hermeneutics.stackexchange.com.7z
48f556d22bb7d3008e97ceb1c46642968b7795f0ea6e9c2f2aee946cd4670a42  hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
7c185e26e3dee7d6ece5df48a901b99e5ce18762eab40fc6b6db9391fe4b1b69  hinduism.stackexchange.com.7z
ecc513f9abf99e8b91478359b977bad61c1e732b7a02e25ac00a2a4aace2cb89  history.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
64c9e1d9e78a9a1001703a7f372a6315a72f2950c91ec0bfdfb849b10c7b3d42  history.stackexchange.com.7z
1c88c79c223d94602bc6b9e3bdefb40a941d117cdddc0ee80efb81e17276f575  homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
0efb0fcbfbb933fc7331a4ca49574304218057f280b5aad545f8a2cb8609ed27  homebrew.stackexchange.com.7z
a91aa3b2f44ffbf260e1d68f7a2b4706c3d1a75e63bf920c92cf7fac8f656ec7  hsm.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
8824eb2c0b1ce06505866b0f8ce18eb27bf5cbb48afbf4881bc8a690d0aee14d  hsm.stackexchange.com.7z
ae32d6cb0b338fdd3dbc4635f707e0172ea3bc627d2481b41e40cad6eefce9a0  interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
7db0cacb70aa84c9bf957774e7064fe5c2ab37c98ed22ffab1899306c75a078d  interpersonal.stackexchange.com.7z
6dd62e222ef3cb3948f00fb80ecd90afb940ead6c434ac125d34e223b04a4533  iota.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f7883f0373c18f455929c29b140220bd9c0afecbff88c426fa0562cf333f2432  iota.stackexchange.com.7z
88609c4c760ce9f017eca9a571d34bda86703d0ab9aa8ca9c5a1228f6c967871  iot.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a685978d9264a9de54c60726ffc1c99a8a30c16945734fc4d9820917acba4998  iot.stackexchange.com.7z
d87eb5fd3ba538069a056f031fcd5b882ee5a0a83f912caec65ee7ad5d529741  islam.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
0774ef643c5e224c04c924732def82e3aa18295584741df929f21e4577f2dcce  islam.stackexchange.com.7z
74e499f468374ad5ca9e5e02d6452a5edef9cf73b2bdd1605ef5022f65498564  italian.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
478d17791bd8456a380448e99bb61351fc6e61fac2b7f4f3e9b5e5eca7c89f55  italian.stackexchange.com.7z
b5e9ef0870f5d564470769450c058d943137d3df8101498d11e8e713d90f45cc  ja.meta.stackoverflow.com.7z
55775798efcf7c52e8688c26a9197ec215c07bbfa1a06efa7c34370b67314e44  japanese.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
04c353a8b116107c2d40a88887937aa025c215bc0a3fe05b44a229212cd8c7f9  japanese.stackexchange.com.7z
597b7525d2d3cbc85774a2844e47ccdee774337c26160c8f13a78b723c9a26b8  ja.stackoverflow.com.7z
bd09d9ba7c7ee1813c7cf8da4ab14d49ca76f07139868088fccae88b65028e26  joomla.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
533dcd3962393512606525596fec5799206c8a49650dd9de01a1fe5968739064  joomla.stackexchange.com.7z
6832b34c78ba1a37899d2c5d8678e6c29f215568bd798705ac389aa43e715d34  judaism.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
8f52b28e27c30dc98d0333ee9dcb275e60217533ccee1be678e80c0b3d84fb7b  judaism.stackexchange.com.7z
37aca7ae0e64f8a6dc4f806bff969ae0b5437c9cb2e2d4a0ce3a08552de7ee03  korean.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c890a777d91e05d5f03bddedad2ce520fe36e807401ed3b28e0e8d3fb6fd2d15  korean.stackexchange.com.7z
f277f53979b61e73350ca5a531b26a83f89459153a32cf30131162839439bea0  langdev.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4e136fbfc130f2c8870b4bf9b8848e0e05960e223b1cb3c5cccc3559921e0c9f  langdev.stackexchange.com.7z
783023622599ab8f950bd24f13f08c8748cf2eba1a76a24c70690fdc709bbd2d  languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
e10bdfe4c5fd428a593d541b5cadda377d24e5a03ba9086e026692ac6c8b870a  languagelearning.stackexchange.com.7z
9ba7ecf64a7cac650dd452d5c29d443e75a1636384781ad19d25ef9ef2b9a935  latin.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a9cf76c9aeef95f9084e984ebf57dc3b2b7d4d58c0e80eb96254e0c51564c308  latin.stackexchange.com.7z
17489156cbcc4513ec943a89894ad86a26345fc9ed8ceb38d3b0c4cf0eee4a00  law.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
9fb27b5780b866bd8e8b3f8dac8bd5e06df47e1c80c0bb670a11f7479b0bfda5  law.stackexchange.com.7z
a431f8e5a81e64764b964ab43405bf71ce60db9178446af40015f1d4978e1d25  lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
5b5bd150b1ed4db38b97e64c807f96c2451d571a43babd5b92ae1b1f3e03ec66  lifehacks.stackexchange.com.7z
165f17fbc11d9d90478344594f9700ddf65a99a92b6c383a6301b05457534ae2  linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d8752adf0b2c18ddfa46b6c433558a40ec3b2a0b7a1c3f8554c57784ea3c2e69  linguistics.stackexchange.com.7z
8bc5502720e2da0296a775f9e50aa4e1918ddd94673eef21f8e90e835d54e0f2  literature.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a871ecbb82e421773d86b3306d0c2656bf7345670bec5a1abbd24e80f05e8143  literature.stackexchange.com.7z
03ceeb2115b1c217ca11e744690bd700171ba54381ec83ebd9abc07f3ffa5eb7  magento.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3504afcbb3a78cb0368ab2a7e0fb5ba256c678179eaf01987727eaf9724e9487  magento.stackexchange.com.7z
48d8d524e032056fe2446fa1070edcd5dd9b541f9cf4d52544e6274c26b085d1  martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
03043d524375ea98820d4d175b5b105755fddeef5a08be0ca747baa097f14445  martialarts.stackexchange.com.7z
854a9ffa78caa79a7d98d104c2ab89f1aac48735b027ba923a81de37f7961e66  materials.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
07598435896998d9a414873fa6695bde0505c81bc41bf6c7a50591e1d7377e4c  materials.stackexchange.com.7z
9e63cb1494dc9995da8c649ec53ebdc95f810048c44d5e79ea599c3130166b70  matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
fb5a2dac24809a117e8cd7b0a391bcd2d09d05ef98e3e1ce8d029a90440056e5  matheducators.stackexchange.com.7z
81a1afc70df6897ee938f348a23e30d8756e0b80fd5c6d8d52dc21c2a97b654d  mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ae95d733b667ef05c8ed4d87af2c2cc6af4091e7b7c6049a2f7d5a4c6aceed24  mathematica.stackexchange.com.7z
7c84b525d0b2f76643eed41974c1d70525bb070846362c7e810a6ac96ebdd7c6  math.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
2f9f82c9ebbbdff05b09e120583edf5cabe44339082bbdddd224460423777950  mathoverflow.net.7z
180f01504a974b43ec036200ebd322b50a7e02fbe03106a21011bdf5d71aab56  math.stackexchange.com.7z
4671fd299650901c3444ce4e06e0041a2c9c0a297c9d29884dc5ccd3bbe13266  mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
8f18b6b417b6ddfdec3889f430f3bb311b2c88b6fbdd5691a63fe9ecec294895  mechanics.stackexchange.com.7z
4076bfa9239070f7656afabde15f4f587323654675e55e4435edde298372042b  meta.askubuntu.com.7z
c9a92b62060b0402990608805dd5fb81833b8db2f8784dd8bc6f01ed3e853a2e  meta.mathoverflow.net.7z
a7fa2efdf14517a5d9047063a31e2c4660d49263c2ef1f66cf4927a9f5219c3a  meta.serverfault.com.7z
59e511ab134cd43ccb7de4d94c6b2aa740c1757f9c445824c8faf4d5c86aec67  meta.stackexchange.com.7z
362dae7bb0a0e656dc7a81ac5cfb52deabade4e8285b9c4114ddc8883db6204b  meta.stackoverflow.com.7z
04fe48964f6591fd3d89981ab2402a3bd31f0303f43664d6384cfa8f543da57b  meta.superuser.com.7z
fabde74c91e9a2934c00ae9f3b75f525d1412f30f8113d11845e7afebdb0be0b  moderators.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
dd73136e6dd6264696aad671ba3132244f969454d5b3e6265ea1ec96fd399928  moderators.stackexchange.com.7z
ce9e2debf6dba11bae8a25429cb21301cfe8a9bb5104d8a147a0635f2a510d82  monero.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
95f65a1d980fdd948b50db5600844a6c6819ddbcdee6b5baecd4c3395f3d6690  monero.stackexchange.com.7z
579af4dd55eb7769f9c00f1b8288ad707a43b344f025e1cf0cd9cad7443e2638  money.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
cbf4ad4e23ea52a1ff4b1578c5345efaf565b760eb23803b709d6e8ba1c0d279  money.stackexchange.com.7z
9b68d1869d08f311511795ceca7b7d4bf325bc28b42c3d761cfb1b1020d50818  movies.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
5a20a99d11b0e130a1ae6b5747eb7f1a12521d6cf13ee52e2e0f3518c8c5d3aa  movies.stackexchange.com.7z
4c7362fdf38aaf14c625ccbc6f1e5614bc7054955529ab56bfec2c2187946ea0  musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1313b682dfca10edca5fd78ff9b589184843aa2ad7d9654ba1fc17fe586b0b74  musicfans.stackexchange.com.7z
c5e8d052b17abe4a69e338c077760e0a0a899e8d5131416af471e232291e8787  music.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
012fd3facf6ba5156de16a69def5e2b62a3d2e31b4f312da58e57e67e2a5dc36  music.stackexchange.com.7z
6ae2163b2ab2e58ab6a131a540960e2d37fcfbd271f67a7b648f09bdbeefcbeb  mythology.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
702a2a0ed274ffd0e9fa334c78ace1c654fed5064e600f43ea0a7739fcc7acda  mythology.stackexchange.com.7z
e2dbfc46f77bedc50bd26fd0a0a7b5af6839dcb628e96e68627f2b9ff2d8e884  networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
677db67cbb922085d03a36051224c121ec4e275a9feccdff9d7b321ef607ca76  networkengineering.stackexchange.com.7z
5d6a72d172cd585d7ae06baf3a7a9536901d34c191b61685adf5f3353a012595  opendata.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
46d322f91204f1b539682f1ed1f07a627207a8ec0a4987caab04a66818ceef3d  opendata.stackexchange.com.7z
a0393e33ebbedd84a68bf152fad6f78d3da70e30d64ccc38c3292dad5f9927e1  opensource.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
31eaf98d47f79e70692a7d8e16db7090f30d7a97ffd31b3359bd545a91e6a259  opensource.stackexchange.com.7z
792be9f1daee74dbdfd10bbb04709debb46e406286c7c8508e8fdc4ac8a3af28  or.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
800f93f17a49f7072e60ee39f81d754f1bf353c2d12e848c56ed49da03705163  or.stackexchange.com.7z
05cc602d66d16ac9226a400817644de8e4038e35e959e85dc786155cecab556b  outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c2f883d2eaa5418ba910f0dbea80ff7baa5226c8016d23fff98e94b5ba863e43  outdoors.stackexchange.com.7z
bf33a4efa0a66968336d457f32b01b14b5064a927afc3ca27d1074063ec5e218  parenting.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
2afebfff4d70d8e48b8b9407db4729194d440cde18d51e6907aa67b6d1c855bc  parenting.stackexchange.com.7z
c36d85ece71331123854f1954d157d159f728e36531fe89c42e4a80acb47aa85  patents.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
5a6a0e2ef23bb59fc2dac35728ee9a8a28c4b0ee3d16c6838d13f764c32667f8  patents.stackexchange.com.7z
bbafdc7a7d573f04f4fb6f868a49f9ee05748168f734a24374d17fa98f207047  pets.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
7336fd429bfc5d7cd2dd13211c26890fa9c25bcdca2c19e18ca944ff8b4f1be8  pets.stackexchange.com.7z
2725cc4afe0531bd9082d2ff398915551d29c6159adf8828544dbabe3e3cea74  philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
45176c32e7b5d587144e18bc3e159e6189730b08b8969cd61092f5dc08436939  philosophy.stackexchange.com.7z
3d7076d7d838aa77841cc9d5089ca6796af4f337a00ca737bf71f2514ea0ff74  photo.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a1635ffd12720ddb8754fe7b5e073153e3446d1313eaf36a24b694d6e5025384  photo.stackexchange.com.7z
3dfa57ddff9456cb3437c0abe3ab383f36c0f95b8828cd2b1d8f84d327e8954b  physics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a3a23677ddfe7bc74caa7116ae05b0bbd26fa34f1e24356f212ccfcc48d01159  physics.stackexchange.com.7z
5c71e42c4d0bc49fc245a3b3f3d9419fb936789be7a764c1096c977c4e9a8055  pm.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f8e5924c2afe01847d5a0d53e451372733cc7debd9ed182431ff01a8b3a767ec  pm.stackexchange.com.7z
43f9cbbe86f6c511c1365f4120878e3be03293fa72c8f54fc3c146de91686181  poker.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
7c7cbb49b70e12d7352bd47d05c9a173f6e9bd0033a27a119dcbb7a08d0191d4  poker.stackexchange.com.7z
09a1d57c92a302934791dc396bf60aeb1e4e9efa299692c7b30b9527724aa1de  politics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
095bdc881705e7916dcb0f2c598320fb29b6c868a6a44c736e03ebba96e6038f  politics.stackexchange.com.7z
7b79992c4cb1c95efdd923e60e5b4059775ae82fe80521620a80f0f368200751  portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
438fd56765466821c2b9398e1efedc73ef8a7ddeda82808eb5affdd805b20c0b  portuguese.stackexchange.com.7z
057ca97587589583d53eac11c4a2c8c664090304b0782d2d048bc9046ab15489  proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a966d37bd34df2fda3409854bed10e3a299dc17c74ed29412eeb0710047595cf  proofassistants.stackexchange.com.7z
fc8d08c2d8ef1ad856b0714339de06daa87306cfc3e61d2c24a1668d68b687aa  pt.meta.stackoverflow.com.7z
521ecb4f25263e5d63bc8d3040c89110b835f9f8edf1b1d99d0c09726536b288  pt.stackoverflow.com.7z
eb7554edb72168a4ffc5ae1dc7762929a5739c569b9d8d55a2cd3a458bd2ce5e  puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b0f046ad6d0110ca449134d01ba4bfb3edc788ec01aeb61904cd6d76384a1578  puzzling.stackexchange.com.7z
f51ae363c57e8148bc6930cd4706ba669f38a7d0ec54d0f5dbf46646262b39e3  quant.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
0dfa1f6e7a9ac74fcfd6e97d9a8214fb4e0bea6fd414cc601c0c253c536209b6  quant.stackexchange.com.7z
484186d3c254fee956a47eeee06dd1b758df85c6fe0ea06ed7252373a85c09cd  quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ebdb0f9d907ac49c21ea7f0ef332e139c8e3a4d16edc313694b6ee4388b02916  quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com.7z
5f4587e289abc6ac0a90b823a97da32d312456586f3ac857d4d660064e5d90d0  raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
0e47ab1131d83398d015c5677fb06a0d8bd24ea1337d89d877883048d3930116  raspberrypi.stackexchange.com.7z
d9c3d502b7497b3d8715778242ac835b76ad22ef229dfb9d20e6bc95527b5eb1  retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b349a2fe9431219224c15742ecd1056389b2549ad56b4067643e8112a52b2a2b  retrocomputing.stackexchange.com.7z
b140ffb05cc3f0d54fcb62da4bf5b91042e85e0afd01f5cb78f92e2cbb2e3017  reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
17d6975c4f77badb24034aa7d7df442939eaaab84c928d739f9e88c3d76f0135  reverseengineering.stackexchange.com.7z
5eee854c8368def1f19dfa60955f09194999e032f7bc69553219d19be62f4469  robotics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
fd58502a7405439d11b0f43d7dcffcedfab846e7bc452eb8c584c087add87ac2  robotics.stackexchange.com.7z
0bf936f0860372a9b684ed3d5a0da38457a46302c98c995f3afc297e2e925adb  rpg.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
86f1040c9843d25186952a1b8706e93e54a44ab2e89d42be5c2b1b0818338f00  rpg.stackexchange.com.7z
93ebc52df552791ef2d024fe4e76b5cd7d0fbed070203e5ed6e7d7f1cda35ce2  ru.meta.stackoverflow.com.7z
ca7200f1527dc5774708eacb4e96793a55ec971466896aedeea53eb3404e0ff1  rus.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d013a64c4c62bed5ee864db734337784701b4fc0be76ff9ce2c02447a6436bc1  russian.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
9f4672d87ee144edd9f25d2adf09156de7e38482d113af35df2f40bd91139c74  russian.stackexchange.com.7z
6ed2ca06de6b135abcd43942946c8bc191ea8e221da5064d77ef5761ee931798  rus.stackexchange.com.7z
f3a37a50350b4c236e808e6e0da46e6b7ebd42e399977c9e8e80ce51bfd9e531  ru.stackoverflow.com.7z
4a3ee197096226bda1e0fbb668a9ae1ff375c1906d3f01937856b0c677648469  salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
722627cd01656d4fd435b3e89bc97deab5b81d68e8184b9bf90e0a79463c9d00  salesforce.stackexchange.com.7z
01c8c290702c3deff73592e921e5f8559be72e23d7194990a2ec3bddf2c943bc  scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
2396ceb1a9e2bcd57bf16fae49b9bd3db0a2ba6e6a6f47f7118f1677408aa620  scicomp.stackexchange.com.7z
5865836ace132c96614e47060f8fcfa0911761cb0e1df7d30c2ba8d1e9f6cac7  scifi.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c4cef1f434ff340ee1198a1524ca576686acbbdda9fd94229a5ec27712dc1342  scifi.stackexchange.com.7z
fb0db7b4d5eab656edcd31de109fce7ca7e97bf94dbec0e0cf7e4019173b219f  security.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c36802a967922c18431f6d455250d7ae24690d57363a4100270d596f74cf81e3  security.stackexchange.com.7z
e3b0756725451870825b02760e5c6babdee01b82366628e442af04d0a65b86f3  serverfault.com.7z
f52eacd160e99e291554382fd40b7afcb7bbde8fe4aa3bc6bdd4ef6470a1bce3  sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b34fec2bb6491016ca9cc179c3e8cc686255437f85c20b0d01bed1e1d7483703  sharepoint.stackexchange.com.7z
4cbf5fdf2adb0f594e02a13be8bc9e398ef6fd7d97f3e8fa83d386909439c9a0  sitecore.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
6df134a36aee3454faba053423f2a646ea05e00291f7ed2a1f4112c5f12d173e  sitecore.stackexchange.com.7z
af79324755559acbd3d68a8e6b917557b4df6997e11cb582b4ad3759f2c7c5ee  skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
43ac74861cf5a35571e268d9a3f3d13441a2c63cf8ca41404e87c9c3d460d1e6  skeptics.stackexchange.com.7z
f4fa9d567742ae629ea42669633191c8f0e74ec21739bae72493f1fd6641e4a9  softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
e85deb577662aee6f1380de2bd313f5802f47c9762b0cc99bf23eaf662b7dc51  softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.7z
7a38c7c35a39e8c5e4c1f1bbb8484bab70e8b7347d732412b747b736031f6691  softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d558b4179a96f9d418a0276c0dfb3f76b44d3b8b8fdeeca99e36207061df6c28  softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.7z
cef0166e25d967fff7f313bf215b4b04b236484406e6925c52378f92b37b8176  solana.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c87af79c77c6683834e1f7110fce6372d82cfa0bad2bf4be7c99992aeb756565  solana.stackexchange.com.7z
1910eb884e7f19e1e171d501e8c05ac5025e6c55f4747a5e7ef5edb5314a86bb  sound.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
74516e04187c2dabe6aa1451adc490f3dcc60d8316fe172a6961e27d95d0cba6  sound.stackexchange.com.7z
2b7f6690170fc6649066a6eb07f42a53f7c8fb3434ef1601cd819708457902a0  space.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1102a6b05a9e170113954dd43fc14e39f4361f60a1b5b3260a22235b495b0785  space.stackexchange.com.7z
edba3751add45b523d4e6dbb8f5757ba691073e827a2ca5512b20b368a1434e1  spanish.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c11c508dfa816473933dcc5ef2f4e5ee26244fd191c8130a13dfde033c369e63  spanish.stackexchange.com.7z
bcc8bd0b1fc55b65addd87a811db51e1bc5d942fd3659c49a57da47b7e764f36  sports.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
36f3710a485ab31f220ed92e1a85d77cb4d826742ef7dbab59e0a405691cfd1c  sports.stackexchange.com.7z
92d8cbd6f7795f3c3b80dbd1faececf1090dbd9586fca4309425c9c4fe65a83b  sqa.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a112a5c6e501335b64c29b74d51cc3c7699518344c6eaa5b3faa97c472225be6  sqa.stackexchange.com.7z
c4ebffc9ed91bdfabb8c2265ce9346fdc86b1aa4158062c987a6f6dc813560e0  stackapps.com.7z
96f2ddc51fdc5bf34b0654b46e8e01996d5ab5e5431a64418b445c83dcc3112d  stackoverflow.com.7z
b3114effba9d1e60b5d7e8969edb4a1bf18d9ff8b83e9b60e88d79482026f507  stats.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
441b57ab891dfb6648b4c47400d8f2cd27e5e94c2b73b09a6e0a72e76c012fb7  stats.stackexchange.com.7z
594e4ff6dd57248ecacc816c1918d52afa4f4f8ebac965c48fd3291db319e86f  stellar.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d0284d15f812231cc24d85827e5dbe113d37cc894f7afdac9425c2b2595ec1dc  stellar.stackexchange.com.7z
8391a3dd5b1b71910c6cd920928a427509d123aac852798ea0ae3ad9f579ab04  substrate.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a1de16d20b216d38653d3158861bcbd60c80fc35f9e9db940ea3f2845657ed8f  substrate.stackexchange.com.7z
c814536cc5e48427d8debec71a632a32185074d155c06bc6a32866a21b2f293d  superuser.com.7z
1276dfe537d6e0a990006c1835065f3d4089a4d817067aeff85e7d47440a948f  sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ca88d1a3feb9b573208cac8e6b62bba765925080f20e959bb9eff4e800ede5bb  sustainability.stackexchange.com.7z
541e3f649cf35f2e863c55feebbc2a2d4fef349a9202b6d3b84445e67664eccd  tex.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4cd79bbf5831432b689a396c7539bec866a6acfcb7d2b4cda124b77d8a766e11  tex.stackexchange.com.7z
f34cde03dca975c3847cd1ea95ba97118959be3d95453f0bfe936c5683efbd5d  tezos.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
57004e5d34263ef6063a4c24feb378df763ba3f481c30e557891abdeff08f683  tezos.stackexchange.com.7z
66b4cb0c1f5c3e2945b9951ff0ea685ad44f1b1ea5200adeb5548dd16f520f4e  tor.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3789d356ab4b41366c5591590a2b5cff4544c1c0df978a55890fba13240aebd9  tor.stackexchange.com.7z
18a342f32b7e0eb733636903ff0eb8ef1ff64f5932d29433d936e114f0fccfb0  travel.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1714041e0919dc58afe60f9ad655b8b243b81d61857b1f2e0a569af1b44c6326  travel.stackexchange.com.7z
18f494647a945cf28f54bc2143cfa372b007ae1055ede8407bc856e330f4ca6b  tridion.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3a5fbbce80746e2d1ea142ab55a74701d3ba5f5ade767aefe080e9800ccc8228  tridion.stackexchange.com.7z
f14527105a81d93cb82a8759cc44828d829edde111c4306e502efc9486a18e37  ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
af3e428f69414249eb5ad3f41faee06a9280fe33f7cf9b4c7fa997565f597fd2  ukrainian.stackexchange.com.7z
b0ceab1b3bd66686bc2ca83e33a4e70d196d19d012a1df6d027d88dba5c7e460  unix.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
73075fa664291165e93f83abec7ea325ec0fcd41c0e656013d1fa3f4b368e351  unix.stackexchange.com.7z
e0d00edff4b0c614daef8b0e94466edf524c2d48bb2d0f99c30c2d336b372662  ux.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
0c8bb0ce2209046c3f75f2e8aff91af98a4382c0bb8a6a4d3e6e1e08ae8b4722  ux.stackexchange.com.7z
f2caa866729a1ae1f0b46c293346b5a58ede6444b18a9a16993fc6cae300c986  vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
50bc96078e657a6f5c58fb11df61d83f5febd0922ff22c881bb3157211066aef  vegetarianism.stackexchange.com.7z
a426d2055af6f3871cb466bf45dfa7b100d7132b7e5b3dc6f0194ed5d3c483a1  vi.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
9ed86ffadd6c4e912f9ddb461ba3fbacbe9e7f736adb96187c52a9162d2c87a4  vi.stackexchange.com.7z
4533551b5edcb81b58f3b7d3a1d05a0402f83a4e1c8b624b6cea4dab0a918836  webapps.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
7b466a6fc147e1837f731d41e8011642d31201f1fd6f19da84ec04ebed21138b  webapps.stackexchange.com.7z
6d11b92f98641a83c6a42f923c2f80a1338bc2a844299e943083bcad192edada  webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
87323f1e839089a0c52ae2b515bc899ca55ac1ecffed411e856a66070717a9b8  webmasters.stackexchange.com.7z
9cf2a5c230b6d2206b12bef4b67af6bab57451e6af8225346bcc18b7d0eabf21  woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
0ff61f8e9d522c511190564b1b7264e10313201f6831c5c12b3b87bf29e7768b  woodworking.stackexchange.com.7z
c45cf6e7710825431f58af56d73261a652de17ce63841a801f716c4c885e92d4  wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
872d0763fb0d7393b9757d1a87152f4b37338c90b16e701ca672a4231d11cc2a  wordpress.stackexchange.com.7z
fbc8074edb0d6b5aa70895243fa3a2a20b44676a06a1eab5138438f8c13c2064  workplace.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d12b1278415dd5f7b94ea255c16c2dd24553ce041399118dfa0548d5c8dcea78  workplace.stackexchange.com.7z
d2658e2b79565a34aaafcda959da1c11ace7639c8b46dc1a2a9e2beade2ef3ba  worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ad07970d6368a3dbc4dd7779a958a8b9c66839bf6bf02854f082ba764acc5271  worldbuilding.stackexchange.com.7z
049e6db6fb8af0740b9c156f1a026d8dd35826b2160f61f3bd776a88a4cb1166  writers.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
71fe5754f0ab2563b25db5916702469a4b59895e03195d72abbc49ecf6eb6f9e  writers.stackexchange.com.7z

Historical checksums
For direct torrent links, and for data dumps predating the new data dump process (but unfortunately not the checksums for them), see the community-compiled listoff-site mirror of data dumps.



Data dump
Revision




June 2024 (original)
1


June 2024 (re-release)
Separate (official) answer


September 2024
Separate (official) answer




A set of SHA256 checksums for the regenerated 2024-Q2 dumps has been added below.
Checksums for future dumps can be published in whatever place makes the most sense, but cannot be distributed as part of the downloads. Please feel free to create a new question for community discussion on this topic, and use the status-review tag there when a request has been defined.
2024-Q2 (regenerated)
fd79c4836c364c15e9ef7275629e18cfa9e3fd9464791d5ab731d1534aaff9e6  3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
83ad983248d42a79cd6f93634bb94ee7cc600af31ab26f414ac6bd0fb886b3f0  3dprinting.stackexchange.com.7z
516bc8b26c79165fbbd8792044abc33360d26c021294cfd66f14e27faa3ef660  academia.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a9dbef05ac65f9b6e92e47eba342cb9cf7e9346eb78fca3684958f530ca5c66a  academia.stackexchange.com.7z
9d347147e409586ffe623949d9b91a06f2e815fa17102d767dd53353f1eeabab  ai.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b99fb3be5e5f3510f6134d78f461aabd57a55e25e899c36e960b6cf8780fe92d  ai.stackexchange.com.7z
59a0b02e6ea896ef62c3541d14ab92c8ddcc846bfd2da8604c8b3b13ad36cb7a  android.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
0e38137c0d1873f2d1556c9ea385c6a2ad51a28532db74922d6829dfbbddd7b0  android.stackexchange.com.7z
696676cf78aa762fc10671482decd0d25d23a4e2cc02d53643c0c09ca3e4974a  anime.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
8867dad8c8de8a54e9132fd76ae189d61bd8190712a0140c38b86b47b4a00ded  anime.stackexchange.com.7z
7b103e83cb1347368ff7cdee7dc20f024a01f0f04a3a0a24c1a9291e282571ed  apple.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
defc4e4268aae45c330d41fd663908b3f9f6129712a786d4a26a34408aec79af  apple.stackexchange.com.7z
daf295f8b48f96033b0bca056385b5f25d47499a22671e3398f62bd059c4ecf2  arduino.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d30e8d21253a397c94a9be6ed894d1ddbdd605e46d1eefbe609f401d2b22b8af  arduino.stackexchange.com.7z
9a3ca62a9bfa1822edaccb7bb638f20c2458ca0ddfa0cdb1ea00ff6501bde31e  askubuntu.com.7z
134adbfa50d15fcc60ecfc70fe11113ce24654ade6167e00d19ceb3e9a07b2ed  astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3fa2b0d7964ea29ff403278b502d4360a42e933371b6e7a7d6eeaa44408f01df  astronomy.stackexchange.com.7z
7787867f4737f791fb0857f03b46cb70f0b4371e6d646eac0d93d8e0f19d7adc  aviation.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
0a962aef9380a61932040ece108cda672e8756d3136623c7a97c31f1ddfc1fbf  aviation.stackexchange.com.7z
346373d2880eee83e7e1c54864c2d536a540a94b84122b5cd6f569c29043dff8  avp.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
fc5c1601165f82e949252c78d123417c19f175a591167ed5e2106a98abf82ea0  avp.stackexchange.com.7z
9b3ed90f00ef77a976027e6a764c02764f18722df2dd539184eda237f1b0fa86  beer.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
747e8964d691db9a951d0c029cf099d66b1de54bf413508bb910043b7248de15  beer.stackexchange.com.7z
51f96d6bb41976321bfbd7ea3dd196ab8dde45f1dccbee8a8ee901c9615a61d8  bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
826d64ff8eea443e062f9422f74d4c0ecfb6d61f1910e2eb423859c0eb76ae50  bicycles.stackexchange.com.7z
58b2d6448f6800fb5c9863772f3c79dff0bd0231c99fac25bf8dafa444c20b7d  bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c572da9e3bfb792d2dfd818386f1d2bb9a8050d2a4914ad1bbd6ea3c93c64263  bioacoustics.stackexchange.com.7z
c14efb3d9b9d2cfcef4e78cfa34fac82dcad6f5aa2a50a473e89c89bef9f222c  bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
44213498836c51903cfe9e279b423f1b45a606c298cafa6fd90b15c5566ba981  bioinformatics.stackexchange.com.7z
e00d6af8893c8f39946064ec82822a7a64808d21256b9cfeaf33e4485ff017fb  biology.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b0dad4fc372dd3768baa6d40b523037a9ebf34798a7bfa857b07362f35414cd2  biology.stackexchange.com.7z
88ed545209ff2e6143a07c07328fcafbdeb25dff9f6181863983d8090c8e3939  bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
911a242cb336ade9d56d03b1ace735bbbe9d928ca4e362604983231324d0c6a3  bitcoin.stackexchange.com.7z
7f674b1625e78d0f17e5b656e402be02ebb54057bbb5235209e4072a99613746  blender.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
cc2db14eeb09cac71a9b45c8a273d4ff87f63767c86d2b87fedc00e3d7345ecc  blender.stackexchange.com.7z
2eb2f5a08f03e18d25fc979add70bbf127a20f61f62b7826f2637871cc3745e0  boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
304c1fe5a80fc2b45b4ad17498661f66445384c1e26fd1565746c58d50eacd9b  boardgames.stackexchange.com.7z
040dcda48be3e57cc06d718bb062b6d7f93d97ab7f183c48378234691916aeb7  bricks.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4064dd7cbe69fce70dfc561ffe99b7000f0a9de78e1daab663c7fb8df5a56338  bricks.stackexchange.com.7z
abde0d4ed8adfd89894cc08414ea84d5091d2582a80761213284a547cff7fe79  buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3c1f56da26198ddd671d31d762e422176c972faa90c0d04762725a701f790545  buddhism.stackexchange.com.7z
6ab2153d221c47a89fe085cbc66217e8d6355444df2f75e44b941cbec0067221  cardano.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
6be7dd1b40fea7a3549dd5c14b9348ded7285df548588c3010c3a25379b8ca36  cardano.stackexchange.com.7z
cf5acee5d6f100ec18da98d5ee1944b7c4126e545e5ab44030a27bb58b5eb356  chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3a0f99623821145905bd16421666a15f8eee32cb1cc33425affc299126269bc2  chemistry.stackexchange.com.7z
47ef5fb8d6527531d46384005ec31a4bbe416f4932a2463a29c37d89ea9462b8  chess.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4dafc1876c9f789507d529a7a7069dc8016c461aa17a381b408b65113eeb3fbb  chess.stackexchange.com.7z
85c093fb2f443eab0ab1baa8a005b1abf40fec04cd31cea62931e966163598a8  chinese.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
648977396c4d69568604b7a83269c3ab043be6e6d99808a4f25e852be21d3c32  chinese.stackexchange.com.7z
c32ce4c49777e77617114a408d2c085fc7c406c60bf26488c67c25873497cd92  christianity.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
33739136fe7646823f4ccd1b2a9dde1035585de54e0da8ced0937afc965cd720  christianity.stackexchange.com.7z
16e02c55257026a7784dbb9934a1a3aa38100f50f31fec853f744df1477d0a10  civicrm.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
62f7418de39cbae6142575ad09ba58726d63d01f6b539f65ae91f24be8444383  civicrm.stackexchange.com.7z
cac53036a565580c9e13601680d682c50db79ad3d99ca878d3efa8241a7dbb6d  codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c83c1387faee7ede38377c6b9e541fa015351774d24da9239922a1e723578d4d  codegolf.stackexchange.com.7z
b8aa757cdc64b1d3ae1f0b6b892d306772a3fac23abb21a0ff6d4f70be0d27c3  codereview.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f1f31a1401f76bb7e686ffc85712ff2ee37d3d97887b4e0df2dd4881f2ab9e88  codereview.stackexchange.com.7z
12b0cd05c97e8e8da48573a6f86f505c123075dae1cf1d56f24a611b0868739e  coffee.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1f3561437e4c9dfdfc89d74ea27c59983c86ad987da48e29fb9bfb6d933b8d68  coffee.stackexchange.com.7z
63965571f7e4dc849ade5483cab455d63fc99b2a2dced097ace04f21ac5da4f0  cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
8d663a1f89bfd143b40aac8a93652d749ea986785ce09ce9b2e1412a20093a2d  cogsci.stackexchange.com.7z
ccdd36f12fe98128fac93d62fc2db2d132d41fc5dc9adbb6b45c123ab6432c5b  computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
192f575abbad9a6136500db962b3c82258a866c403f7fc842f9a10b26788c020  computergraphics.stackexchange.com.7z
d7171dfe7fe887a69358a4c4494c343f28454c9181bc05655c8734bdcd3184d6  conlang.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f4ba394f7058eb11bc28b68518babbab501b31c68f87372fb449159f70498e98  conlang.stackexchange.com.7z
33a6b33e496d2f6de41a4fc766f1483104812d7c570281839c8c8d5313f5aa7b  cooking.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
8fa6fc643868101279914987f23e5c30dcdabf573b6e4a5755ed1dfeb4439a3a  cooking.stackexchange.com.7z
adde3c9d93f3b45f86272551803d191aea3b7e2418635345aec37377e204c2b6  craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d9ba2861a9c4592e403160e60793fe7ba9e0238cc7b7e1652d2f2a1c7b9ed341  craftcms.stackexchange.com.7z
ffcff10ca3dbddb8f44b36c6dc6a43e87bcdf3ee7d57bbbe90f50134e740cf49  crafts.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
5c222844e9ad8f01cdde471fd902f3960c79b555e88d74e5a354e8f0594e91b6  crafts.stackexchange.com.7z
9f8ef668668a5fd97f195d290c650125102ab7b29766b550108a6263ec2d0f55  crypto.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a1cbbb554f1d49e00c61a2a6b9ef89b2b27827c42e8c3220f1612a125e9541f9  crypto.stackexchange.com.7z
db45296f4865365c94d635c5e9da77f2083c69f797bb9d88a74a459e9db53cc8  cs.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b24527c2e989bae399159e5ad4edcc2530b8790824a83d2e28860f39d369e361  cs.stackexchange.com.7z
4b21749b6a1601f41e44e32f03810089f481443de5576704e3fcef7bf75bee74  cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
cb8772938c56aea009829f65b3c6fd6eaf03ab2ff65b14b347c6cbb26b8a5621  cseducators.stackexchange.com.7z
ce120bf48938552548bb58dc7f9f444d9528c9cb93d79af9a37f3cf62e52fb1b  cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
e8ffbd3b0cab09985caacf065e6ec25c0028791cab8ea34a784a83eecfa78408  cstheory.stackexchange.com.7z
2d2a572b0f8cc817b233e0a14a91dcb3b1d8e959de171b791f31c5eb647d694c  datascience.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
05f524b42f5703e014f11af2f891cd79ecc3ba8b0ab9f926798a2ba1993d3937  datascience.stackexchange.com.7z
4c60670c152d0b494d16b90ae77cfcee2e81618114ed01faad9071463f0fcfe1  dba.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
e0ba8986988b201f234e627eefa931be0be14b5b3ff4c4f042edd8aebc60d243  dba.stackexchange.com.7z
d79c76bbd40a634518f2a566c9eb240de9d7e5dad46492c2e5a5df828bd39602  devops.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
90d3ff5664733411c1343e3c92c4ec9813b4865fafddab1c5f5f1a593806f7fa  devops.stackexchange.com.7z
b0d0de095fcb05a3d3641cb4b9a4cfdd0139917a0d5d803a0e7b1895798eb6f9  diy.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ff3d6862a4efb646e2a009b5058fc0bc594b3ecc35e6e1085f9a7da992f954af  diy.stackexchange.com.7z
2ee4543d7ea10e5ab7b1660754ea4101bf3334f29cb865dc9eba4716143f2655  drones.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
737c2f8bdff86249cf495540f47fd68a87981fef390ea40b864a6172573e4ea7  drones.stackexchange.com.7z
aba0a672ecefede0bac308881d3028be7ff3d6f7b05e4ed362cc16777461fe07  drupal.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
e6d3db69348b312e527328c348d886c7c2759eb5a66536e980f64b2160f0e780  drupal.stackexchange.com.7z
6f502f3ce9862f50a740b30d34930388c12ec461ecfeecdfbf5bd01b3abb3a4c  dsp.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f00c3cc60699758e1a1549d004c5806327470c23ef3288866678a55b0e00977e  dsp.stackexchange.com.7z
b1cd185caa9532b6b7cca0c5952ddd50bb1d85bc1b1c24047b3af1dcd03aec48  earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
804081fb37fb31d7fece122f570037694dc5289675c9e901311e15d9c2129c4f  earthscience.stackexchange.com.7z
4b7ac152ea6d9c62451f34f57f8db56c7e169a2396504df96a759886ec178f8b  ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a075b176c064f16d9a406776be7be071ffba4268fdadce52f6474eda2cf883b6  ebooks.stackexchange.com.7z
a69a42d4f4f99f169952f101f26f422386236350ebf9b8db22c7cc9663f7ea92  economics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
821cdd61450389535f1dae0a6788d402f37b70fb22d6df6e0a28c933539d2186  economics.stackexchange.com.7z
8f20afa9c4f8b42c3735dd194dcba47dfc2d585affb06c37cbfdbbba26eaeefd  electronics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d7d352b2a0f36e7360078aee2487fd598a26485c7ae43df94394fdb38d5f6000  electronics.stackexchange.com.7z
2f909c8b00d1120af2a976fe197db9c0ad3b2e2a4c7a5bda34ca52b82210efc2  elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3a9f653430690e0f217c0c866378e7324fc73a8345499e48bbc7c47acbbc8b99  elementaryos.stackexchange.com.7z
f886f12aa90648408dba30f19e8f98e1126c2497c920819670a281642fa87ab4  ell.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b47a2debda9ca4d4a7425a3f03aab5d38477eb19a99a611943fc557e46e95784  ell.stackexchange.com.7z
f7c9672923db06d8155aabfb22e723aeacbdd82a4ff8bceff7e136d2601b8ecf  emacs.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c14289dbacf4bd1b2cc9cb19087c6252bc81f1a214fe50a2bc83a57057acf638  emacs.stackexchange.com.7z
5d90a2f0d3aad2fc440ea2606b074ae94796e87d9fc236f8be24985b17ef9678  engineering.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ec3ebb401fb9ee04e8bdda0f18fa162564d9cf05af0904fe977e538ebc5bf652  engineering.stackexchange.com.7z
623230ef0f4aa3b814c84939ebf1c4675a431b270abe6fb4c9de5c1a2b5fa57a  english.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ebd4bf13c1224a140d3bf453757332c9528028ab2f35be392f8e306452528d1b  english.stackexchange.com.7z
33bdcc4842b29d0b82bb72c44fadc2ff438f82290361e64df18d8f02641d8f72  eosio.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
058a5c7927de338427c788dc94e447202309cbd1a09251b543a6e173ec6678cf  eosio.stackexchange.com.7z
c40f231d0292d5d009da484c38eacde1e2102f73c9ef5f5cd8fca8b8b76428cd  es.meta.stackoverflow.com.7z
2318daeb67449cc7a68a93027efbed4ca4482992239f451c7c5aabd88040f42c  es.stackoverflow.com.7z
1a671ac45e44ab169ec7a56a50de4e8cc4276099b9d0ebe549924c85c14eb4a0  esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
993acc2d583e2bcff336ea68d227778edc8618541b2ab2f894a515fc8630304c  esperanto.stackexchange.com.7z
bdd174976668c78d9a8837fc1ece04727b12c8f1795354cb1667a937b8b2d27a  ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
2d0412caa5d0e59cb883deaad40cdd65bb7c7016ca5c26da307470001403a914  ethereum.stackexchange.com.7z
3cd8b737c23aa727239e0deac727963e84a6db17caebb8b2b447c537ac620926  expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
5ba684fa42ea275b202406386127097aa50b51cd4610bc6909e5c33b6a88930d  expatriates.stackexchange.com.7z
48e3aa3d7015f5e0d4dfc3b7759ac2121a4278cdf1f0ed8f798c22d7e5271b83  expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ba5500591839e68a9dd771ebc1431ed2ab0a13f523bc1d10544f04ac91b7f988  expressionengine.stackexchange.com.7z
b6e65f59398a2a61a4755d41b0681d6959d74349597d713a1a142ec68d12aa37  fitness.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f0c48cd55dee74cc68fb08386b6a253f690dec0fb7cd5926702befb34df7038d  fitness.stackexchange.com.7z
11fb6393f29bcffe944b99ccba06507a8f55b0ccc4f6827e870547fce0514a56  freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
371c359bd194a09c94ee39abd6fe9879d16972f82c381e0a7201a00fa49ea5f5  freelancing.stackexchange.com.7z
25fc077bda73075e907e20b9de7f40ddf091b0a0b4b5803295878ef84d0fee1c  french.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
37f7013afb34f1c252503857964a07b4c56081a8178cb4db55ec26946034a6c6  french.stackexchange.com.7z
52a7d68d8592a9369e8602458f699184a604e2c3e2c28e8516e31a713b759dc8  gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
5185036d919528dab20e32b4bc0c8dcecafe2b92d00b645233a03ddeb0215fb8  gamedev.stackexchange.com.7z
f8c580a6dd06577eb8e639fd0d54a65744cf207db45a9ba28c9b02f26573b656  gaming.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b32c2437334f5615f036825962572bd4a38a93187092f094cc6f840b2375eda7  gaming.stackexchange.com.7z
c59b1a55dae3587bc4212555411eaaf7ad70ae7764cb173d8e75f74033e6fa90  gardening.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
83dd06853fc44366a8b0f28fc846ce684b7178f48ed6948c663707bfb5e7435f  gardening.stackexchange.com.7z
10208e48a4e98a451af70f61e27d240ccac96642d940c2a7ed60fa93c622213e  genai.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
42b9f99f22f6f6ebb63cea20348b692867949c312909c32237a8a5fdb47844b0  genai.stackexchange.com.7z
4da7de8ca59a1dc22176d8944be62c140fcb9f55e162f5db3e58c177bd7a2e2a  genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ebe86c00411710355e4253c7a2c2d1617a24f58889568ef0e0f56f4333362c5a  genealogy.stackexchange.com.7z
bbba585c584c013bfb5df466f53f7eec3991657e5f61bf9dfcd62b086535c175  german.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c91f244ec5a50e86c29da52393b76154f1e4ae1b53f9281de64b58d214293fc4  german.stackexchange.com.7z
b9200a1cab4f1923702bdf0e9c380abf636434da02038b69e126cc760b5d975d  gis.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c1abf8ee289981bf30a2cbdc49cb9b6d326abc6b48388441199e18ae3ea860c4  gis.stackexchange.com.7z
d97b89a4fe4546c352a2640de98a138258c9eb9e6855375f6648a3337815bafb  graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f573bda7dc57aa2bc15455f33f9f96aca26c04d23bd202438d03828de24e19b6  graphicdesign.stackexchange.com.7z
0c3f3f86d9d0bfcc095bfb5b88780fdc3e7593e07bf55734f7e0d1b8724a735f  ham.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b4045468e0d1487057fd17511920b55362e1b05c5ac2cd8c9b9f91c4c32d2e7f  ham.stackexchange.com.7z
e63f29b0330597d554bafdfa20ae4d0d9b135b1ba64555287f1ba0886b038867  hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
789f18fbb4fde9b2b65965b47d85009408bfc8561757449859de4f4842fa048c  hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com.7z
3c69751ae5a432d41736eb719912fa40b11e104a758c523c4df2d9009a23a520  health.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3518bccd17e109738bc86ab28a0880034911475ba9993771980d7c3c2594f9a8  health.stackexchange.com.7z
d24780dccfa64f0c248787de0e486b9b75e8c1063adee6dfd71174f0d6ff44cd  hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
44e4c92b5a3e6b07568d477d91375d929112853b01237fe9a839f7633636d776  hermeneutics.stackexchange.com.7z
39c92fa25cd3cae2935eb100ec37fea05334945045ba788d9e4ecaea575ff49d  hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
8f8a67ca7e3d99c47b1c6154cd8da19fb1bdb43ece7ef93a2bb328c7da9ede16  hinduism.stackexchange.com.7z
05a3df4a8eaef00fcbb3ff39eeb2f7315cb065507d4030ff71b307b969040c6f  history.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
cff0edaf78a4b8e2c45f9b2319742330970cd35cc7875a5de842cb69c4a3bcd3  history.stackexchange.com.7z
182ff607c4e74fe1c025c60c4fe3bd750f5d24f05379b2e0d7ac59ef584e0547  homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
640bcadbb8fff38acfcf9b398afcf374dcd6f011bc151987711dfb2c2517181e  homebrew.stackexchange.com.7z
3ed55d04ccc19e95df9d5f46298418de1a0e1d0b580f89a1bc09d1454b52bfe1  hsm.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
fc6c409a9d95085ea5878ecb6431ed30756c20ec411847dbcb49a3a4643a67c7  hsm.stackexchange.com.7z
0741d766fde17202a725cc2217ab994521f6db587c1be4845924a6f4a886a91a  interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
8c4dbc241e51ecac9795976e11c43dede5dd96124a75885cd9a5b9b7a6530a6a  interpersonal.stackexchange.com.7z
be206f023246feab56dcd697be5a7407dcce0a1fdbed5e134c0b99a89803e83d  iot.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d1e0c83c3b9c598d2f722b7d60f68ce639053fba381b0c75aff6c120987a7e59  iot.stackexchange.com.7z
a54c6245ddd1fd1d1f616d997247f6a30db78672c54ebcca399ce17f338454c7  iota.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
e982eb0f23d36c4dbec13e9f376a89bf91282a5111b4c4e49d3753dc0be86121  iota.stackexchange.com.7z
bae1e8e1fbffb0e29f10ab7d0c2065294f13b98732943259f301db18a7f2442e  islam.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a30589f204fb00a63b0f55e63f6b06c0d154ecd362df4a7dc6c687ad582ce164  islam.stackexchange.com.7z
9d80a22b5ef638516985a99709bcc5c3bffca35447559584baa8f10388629331  italian.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c1198039d1d7bc80897929d66568e0f1d77c2899a2fa842e51e6eaf5a826a459  italian.stackexchange.com.7z
023e06015d1d5ecf9b1783743d5b15c51351889d2cb39a96eafc8e10ff1a6a35  ja.meta.stackoverflow.com.7z
d4c7fd9f51914ad48aa661d52d019878fd193f48d8cc2cdb4e42e72cf217721e  ja.stackoverflow.com.7z
5ff31df5daf78954f3679be62a06cedf11315020365bc2a711c951ce4b8557d8  japanese.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
206fd53aa828e6188d055a4e3ebfd09238f956caa1552d8739aac1584546e068  japanese.stackexchange.com.7z
b7fad9e92bf9a230386258d99aef9ad1bb6329970ad53aa4fb3fc7d796bb9ad1  joomla.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
85d756f891fd51e79567b0a9a733d57bbfa26fd872f08151998eaf743624be61  joomla.stackexchange.com.7z
cee3256fc6db5ee417bd2f82e189c0bf0cf92185d901f517d9692d1554ad87d8  judaism.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
37b62c4185c5603fec502f6ea148db686932e3c6a1db7cbdca95b842125abaec  judaism.stackexchange.com.7z
c6731d86b672a9330b9fd68b855ffd06c4d388579c3b786ec2f383c73f2b9fc0  korean.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
9feb5f69888534b269cf8806bf184e274aa42d064aa33e4ab6574a038ef9e377  korean.stackexchange.com.7z
cd845aff06c5cfba2bcfaf0d1ef4773b6f2cfe0abe6186321c5449f9792730cd  langdev.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
940dfbabe82a0b45e3c2549a79ed9c6b1bfd7e301dd058a2f30c48b6758b8e6e  langdev.stackexchange.com.7z
0cc54ea4f2fe93ed4890037c732e40ee6819a8d4b652b225527a5609823f56f6  languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a447c6d2ccc9a3bc1feee55cd15e332ec4f45017fc013e5046e8fd732ac35539  languagelearning.stackexchange.com.7z
f3a25bf361af6e766839550c565140468aa21bbc017f989b984f6bcb153aac6e  latin.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c4c8593cd266b3313226c88fd4b258e1d0691cd037875bb287e86b070685b6fd  latin.stackexchange.com.7z
7c0929cded581a550b9ecac0464618ced92d34b5b80e0913244473b98b63894c  law.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
e087ace3472d4870457b5c7b5fe737f1d9cd5378801cf2f77f0d539a58ff758e  law.stackexchange.com.7z
880657c8361dd0225f9909dec8be0a3cf61207266cabc00ec63046632f5f64ff  lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
27f320b8e370f1efdbda28a482617a4939aec1adda6531d5ce5a99668f66c4c3  lifehacks.stackexchange.com.7z
b195cc912efdec76633bf0a1880173ac892a929988ff005447418e340204c55e  linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
407c61f5239448dd061d14cebd42afbe1ee5fd87f5a353c51430a450c16034a0  linguistics.stackexchange.com.7z
f1de47eeb57bb4d1a11375a0ae0f2387949f25feb331f3ec214c8153ec54f7f7  literature.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3ec01447002470a3fa60a28591c1a6f69809656e12b9c600c96e47023f8dde7d  literature.stackexchange.com.7z
006f5577e62b3bc29616b9f51afdf117ba389dc1af195b513a37415913859373  magento.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
015702477523e2cc4b3dd31e24d9b401910e5bf25abb375b235835489618cd9a  magento.stackexchange.com.7z
ce02c3bb33bf7f2e07152c5600b047ed863549ec82bf3b12addfd1068ae2ea7c  martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
154fcafbcf9b2344a48bd933dc0807e6bbb61a9f9cfb20063816b3ae561e2118  martialarts.stackexchange.com.7z
e68aa65e9c08e48f6b9ee2139220d1854e309c629369cb63ccd02db127ed857f  materials.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
521b58510a301cbe96d22654153f9a748d22b304c5bf8aaf633ecba712af2371  materials.stackexchange.com.7z
db5846e7e32c2aedd8fcef5f76633c5296d3c252ac6f19977dbd0accb57c0f48  math.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
cfa14f0b7a26316d1dff88924ec9262f5832ac8fb763bc95ed5929073c8e5b4b  math.stackexchange.com.7z
f95e80c79a99da02786fe69add9ab88caeb990423e4aa225a13d0f0b70082211  matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
5547c090c8e9d6cd55f8a045ede97555862382d6a8770360e3233d236f7372a5  matheducators.stackexchange.com.7z
3a32d430f47c3ab67e4e21c1f3fd6e01a83c23d526872956981a5eacc1030fee  mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d29fde3335996861497599fb8c192b49c0477eed6ab0b8269c8487305f58e769  mathematica.stackexchange.com.7z
3b1355edba0e2905f0335dc8b0958b27c7ce1f845867e856628c38751810ede1  mathoverflow.net.7z
7880bb94e4e347d173c46db1d620e727c39913edfda5ecbe08efc882436c53a7  mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
99d86d5f69fa39e78474dc7add76e75e7c5f7fe811e7ce5ef026c4b9b18cf9c1  mechanics.stackexchange.com.7z
fafb96d0ad1c6fb0266deb8ee6a11e25f7ea98c819f33b39e05eb37c2c5302ac  meta.askubuntu.com.7z
bfe2af460733e37b4c9de9cb7719a99cd3cad3b861e55590830077d8590652cf  meta.mathoverflow.net.7z
0428b5f6c46e463223c9749db752eb206abd5438731bf8e791fc9f28fce845ad  meta.serverfault.com.7z
4210326ba8b1b4b85913a20439bd3a3604f1b2ef0f820eb25dcfb67a2d126938  meta.stackexchange.com.7z
6bb4a6273618c42c7a30ff758323e9e8cfd247f07f87de51bf216bfd7c79d91f  meta.stackoverflow.com.7z
d622e00fa9ac153b3519fd5d88de5d4aa9217a68f58f1164ed57d86b618fe290  meta.superuser.com.7z
c4b6a985f021f68a0f07920dd704d83761a9a69a4a1b8ba1614df0386b977b2b  moderators.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
632c8b0ea024d1020842233f8e9b3d2d597d2c7e696c1aef52cfc313472dd2de  moderators.stackexchange.com.7z
aade67c6554f9e0c0975850a2b3b51495462ed26b813dc5a7a0351f3a70b348c  monero.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1ea390df760c5ac7582effccb803a4c70ed7f06efbba4313e5af91d61b10a45b  monero.stackexchange.com.7z
d7dacf7923d88471946c875f38701838621ebe822b8ce83ebc10b51ab958089e  money.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
179be2c92e750666f6b0f54840cb6c569c0dd1ca73d0e0debdfb5c9205dccaf7  money.stackexchange.com.7z
4a766ad8d2425db3ae6bd7bb9b7db0582ad09c9982d7327f79a86b9678158260  movies.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f963b91ea724506579799d6f97e5ae37353a3deedc733e6a3b9daf282df41537  movies.stackexchange.com.7z
180120c4bce5f6ad604c50cd40fc4a830385a551f24a2bc186de1d2984f5b05d  music.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3199cbc0f1781b91c6ebf736a63cdd1d5ac93c4d5afc6459b8ee481d4bed76c0  music.stackexchange.com.7z
1f6651a0c733d16d019f399bd1a77589643f0c3aa2c26bb30d584401fd1ed0e5  musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
42ca79eaffc7e9573fa36ae71e7de31572fc5ec8d1e9ba0b27c3ba999025a66e  musicfans.stackexchange.com.7z
02aaea30c4e82cfc0c5a28f64ba31c85ba96cd323af28a885d61069803ad3695  mythology.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
6eca845baa3d72fde339cbb28921577ddd144ea63b58563678301234210a5358  mythology.stackexchange.com.7z
6637303a8efc224e2cf8a76f5e120a363978027427cde419c294156287447d96  networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3997aacc298eadaa0e9f14ba9fd4ddb2d9d0295bac657171ccf9e6817a773d4b  networkengineering.stackexchange.com.7z
99c03a7edce737993d5dc63710c2bbf801b99fed284b9ddb9ae8e120a47c7c3d  opendata.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c5eeafa2cc0c2066f3c26d6515fb78b6269e28fc65350cb30b09182acde48846  opendata.stackexchange.com.7z
ff8d74d87ad050299b69b18a48bfe88dc2800a6a407e7ef3afbcd935746d6c29  opensource.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
db507978431038f820714654e6e70615e2f76e0b7909cadcb26a545d13b803a5  opensource.stackexchange.com.7z
2d5a0804f2a153cfe1f41a50263fd094471087614d007c4eb49d2220965eea46  or.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
30f4c6210e38ea2b592dcc6581596f4e402ca799a2f452edd3f8d00c94462f5e  or.stackexchange.com.7z
469992f96ee1ec4d6bb14b58d3594f9440a920baa572a099e2c62f7f7e74ccf0  outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1519a72e40412bafa3df0c895b5f9f0453e2768139caedf03dd0dd0ea0a30bb4  outdoors.stackexchange.com.7z
5fef894c9a3963b7813b74b1a4f96af59ea830f61f7976931b40c6fadf7a1e79  parenting.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1105e6721cbe7d3004824d2f9eb52a9ad3a9b2fd87e22f79970cf8334749c954  parenting.stackexchange.com.7z
a36317fcc6d5c47cd35f41134afab6311c7a74c749d8cc5421ae7d913222e246  patents.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3c39aa91ed96a4ff5aaa3b860d16630f81548dba2d31bf4f2b1478f7d0228624  patents.stackexchange.com.7z
1ef898b9cb5e172e0dc3877940870b89cbe81ee80add71fd2f90810b4cf529dc  pets.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
6caf0407c420f9e82dc6013b4591883d04570c327d3fb62034d42408692427cb  pets.stackexchange.com.7z
bcdf2892e8a13894c71f7122608f756e94b7f5ea107e6ca510b179c8bfc82592  philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c0ac68c54e96b79fa06e3d30d4678581bb03182b163d1c4137c4fb3714b11c7d  philosophy.stackexchange.com.7z
5bd1cdb1c9affc4b07ecfdf776aca782f66b6bae0203919315147d0fa45c5ba9  photo.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a6c82f43703bd0b5a88bd1884a1f3e698f745ec84f6f6ab339e19e96ec400d49  photo.stackexchange.com.7z
44083f3d0369c9b88d6026ed9d052bae0e2b959ecc5642e40302cff370053b40  physics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b81f33fcd06b25dcf35fe4b3957a3cf4a1e50f21b74162df9d403c0ae15fc2cf  physics.stackexchange.com.7z
13909e96661b96f129f8b73e0e4d92edab0d76af90319dac29f1ca3e8c673732  pm.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
fd6634cb43add01cdad748de19fba59b08b5358eb1cce5cb99bcbfe59b09a316  pm.stackexchange.com.7z
4f34e8d676ac6a72b40dec90424d74d808860386879dde64c85a0d557588288d  poker.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3ec210b6f19b6083bd0bc0c5fb70a1c58f2c61316e96c3ad1a55e026696a7c42  poker.stackexchange.com.7z
749dd8152039fb3f1e320a0d4b7f7310a236653a0f29184fa294efc00996f410  politics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
124254c27991885373aea3c3ad707dff536dd5f368d0a2222d6b1f071c7fd621  politics.stackexchange.com.7z
6739d8b6747fba0f5e31babb4aed0e6a36286bdf5eca6abe8b37825fe4eae8a7  portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b5a16f0add29d83ab96267cc6d3b257f3750bc188bdec1e3c4ba73a3c8977182  portuguese.stackexchange.com.7z
628bfaba400ae972bd47bf9c1d71817bb46b057578273eebba9845d91ce6f5a4  proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
0590fa5a9f4fbb871ec0727b4d49d06810b5088ded6c24315e396c2feb5d508a  proofassistants.stackexchange.com.7z
cffce4132dbe50de0c7a86473f5afebbedf11b88b89d93f643b9585554c1d786  pt.meta.stackoverflow.com.7z
8b6cbf4818a03241ecb38cdc0556fac5c8769b6af0a03d619b0e577adc1d43c1  pt.stackoverflow.com.7z
5a813b139f7de116cb5db795949fdcad65e6c31dd17f4468cf651e188e72a850  puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
909b4f89ed01894999230251ddcaac76390c22b499cfb84ef3cc023191a6d846  puzzling.stackexchange.com.7z
9c3719d04caa0cf85f410d40d44420dd264f2d8a205d076956e348372461c041  quant.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3e4f14b24aea80a9336a55cc3ce331b399dfb07bddb61bcf159712cb2039c26d  quant.stackexchange.com.7z
11db7cbbc3a0fb810ef55adcdfa5cd04ea8152b74bd948bf3282d1ad87d69a8e  quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
5517d3c54b30b2bf3690d9e805cc9d1a95426a3e93826d9da8b7e1a917743936  quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com.7z
87fb900826e61cf1b18603b8f2fc2771bd23a14047a9efe5af6994dc3d22ad1e  raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d3af528e3ae8a966f8f58fccd6fb52023f197e9d1353901a1637324681bc86ba  raspberrypi.stackexchange.com.7z
f1fd360009422029da4de935d5523e40c8e80db8cca2bab293d049a35ebfe634  retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ac141d7156dd453c78955347ca5cb0d3d789ec1487ae4ad58c47eb0f7383661a  retrocomputing.stackexchange.com.7z
78fbaa87c68375f91032a2a56cff78de254f9a921cc90b85b8ed4dd11b5023a6  reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4c9b0a9c5689b10249a3d3e50659381863e632dd75a4424f3f41891f7e14a61a  reverseengineering.stackexchange.com.7z
c714d44d9347ea431f44f1dd583fddb047e84d105ac92c13e278ff2bcaa2eda3  robotics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
9c4f0bf008029ffdd8d55347d97313465abf28d00a4b8ca499480c4439cbccc9  robotics.stackexchange.com.7z
a5f8e93f6cb8bbf8871ec0132166a9c2692ee5f7c30ba21989c15ffdb26433fc  rpg.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
de3ada162342954b0c5d51b4ee7e55249739fdcfe4df075dc2c6fe5804498ff8  rpg.stackexchange.com.7z
3edcc469ea5e41e7d40d232c9d6b8d26623b1ac46d67a6248573085d29daee8b  ru.meta.stackoverflow.com.7z
c2e7354aad313fb103f2be11337a59f855dec2fe8d67fdc0f7728eded6e93119  ru.stackoverflow.com.7z
68824706b3c0e7121cdf2312c8c007a7b2ee574f2d8bb8d3a1f4b4ee778c3625  rus.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
408c6694b3a46c33f6c6a6087f406c09470299b13fa42c2284b4eec8bab5faa7  rus.stackexchange.com.7z
9b743b5e52f8e88abb389d5dd1c5f15f78a18a8254450233cfcd0d2414b7f3e2  russian.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3c534d32f82683db8119e08bee624f48c5eb579a89840663c990cf0c5096cc36  russian.stackexchange.com.7z
7616e05d5aeeaa9eeb95a184612b029ea1c865b965e7170f36512395c480eceb  salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
2a42d5a2b71ba9ef3726623a314e8ba156f87b29cda3ca4ec7eba4d15d7e799d  salesforce.stackexchange.com.7z
f4f2095c1319e3af4f70aaef2b103791de8ea96e1f1eb43fb9d279ce0d7bdf51  scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ca3c97aa930332bf16a1a39cb8f711c198316d1cffe7697e2a9ef3e063750a6b  scicomp.stackexchange.com.7z
98d213b0033996e302231d0c27d038605b376ecf7386bfe365e2e0f36aa90266  scifi.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
6e1f31d1dc77353ac5e45575df9ff0c51f0b37ac683b878824bd991f67deda69  scifi.stackexchange.com.7z
76c7f1122c752aacd9fdc817009d77a0a681d2c887ef3397d92b4d747df3a99c  security.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
7fbfc0d715e0db4a82c1107f924f521c65111e384c5946466aa4a461ffdfac4f  security.stackexchange.com.7z
88727c67c6a4e881a6726f2c89d897927c99d91b1df27b523f734b5ff17b4b86  serverfault.com.7z
efd4f2f7309aa5dcc4d6afdfa1f2f1a42343d2e9f6d4695e9445e28f661effa9  sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
bcaca135e94532cf6b5449ba5b8119e78120c4ec9cc6962a2deb03903b96013d  sharepoint.stackexchange.com.7z
6dbf3ce5d20e48bef80149fa595b42ed0d65230fdaa2a9d4b46eb519c078e769  sitecore.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
12f217959e752cc370b98d3c4539930e6e06bf59004fe4fe5ae395470ac12d74  sitecore.stackexchange.com.7z
a3c5b50420f9432b1d4d27ff9c24543a97888ce27177a38aee7854b17482ed71  skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c87c2115ea7dd08b28e8726aa71f4db05c94b51710dfe919c13de8d7922643ce  skeptics.stackexchange.com.7z
3dcc6ea45208b85327c011fe256ed00cbccc5dc1bb90968e491209aa604c10c9  softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
630fb0990bc2e40a52fbe3a868db812d82ddf7d9d332a6109ae4a667b0b87898  softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.7z
f27b3e12fa940e87ae05fb2a498de665916678bf5494a94689964d701e2af9f5  softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
37ca0006b3f3331dd4709136b304efd9d6872add181d6408c3467e624ffa0e3e  softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.7z
7d2d75142dc807b3efc96fd5ed832e96bdc0680be718453f2a73c57d5177fc05  solana.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f8e23b420f976bb759be845728f2e38cb539264eaa806b28fb677edbbcb918ed  solana.stackexchange.com.7z
40a2edd0b18d73001228a20c1f6de77e9a4b5735e4e52091935b55de9f375db8  sound.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
17f95ab648ae300d9b3b7d7c99ae070c4c1f168ccdec905baf7b0556af91505e  sound.stackexchange.com.7z
8646ea565b93dea91d8dbf36a77ca2645f5e01e7fe6a8b6b81085114142c5c6a  space.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
9f38d3c227219099698578cf4301273147b90ec49a683e9649351d0d38d3ba7f  space.stackexchange.com.7z
cb80459af721941aaa86370365f1b2ef2191cb47dcae7eb7006c47cd7abe5fd5  spanish.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4302c84588908121242155f9f47b1acaa8c41bdb4006896965651f18d83c41e7  spanish.stackexchange.com.7z
b0df6142f619d92b08cd097c7440b09ee43ab6417c765346dec241c42954ba31  sports.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
df102a82bd34249c3a7c8902a9e99e42ceabd488bcd7e164c0cc82e1770afbc4  sports.stackexchange.com.7z
2e81cd7a2eee2d18576813f869d31386f1dea314df227d4a7c16f3f2f9bde2d0  sqa.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ed97a2df09ea4f38522140b1c12c1c67420491fd03b007a37393caa1895c5b77  sqa.stackexchange.com.7z
bbc705b3ceae34c3fde97ccb20b54ae6da2f53525b56e2151a7afb4ea360974c  stackapps.com.7z
af29067f8acc171775995e1f02f8a41115b9aa5b5bb51580b4b244e28b0e68a8  stackoverflow.com.7z
277ef3a885f3d8a745a2ff25a46291c34c720c4832bae5fbffaa9dbe59578592  stats.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
27bce7e04fa48ff130acb397c6c9ae6fb2f01a85a6a594c387e7190144f4c87a  stats.stackexchange.com.7z
4fab8cfc1f7c36ac17d690a3e9fac2d3b5c7d31e950ee93ac100f110ef09718e  stellar.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
11cd052f54f6e5a353147686bf44283fff7551f4fc9ee82570bbf9cc74dc8079  stellar.stackexchange.com.7z
2040c7657c49be5b86b6ea5a422bffb83d0da0ccbe99c85b741997d2b24786ea  substrate.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c9789ca0bff775b857a810280e2e8ff20533de8d95f76cb558333394a2843ea0  substrate.stackexchange.com.7z
97b822b656d92e7034617cc3dd115d5aa04362e78645e048187880cefb654e4f  superuser.com.7z
84e6a12d806593c974e19174a49d9802fc930597bb817d365fed63eb14e4c0de  sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
2c6c8c407d49ef068043b1f2c6238e7786f10a6762d2416f052b94890c2154dc  sustainability.stackexchange.com.7z
17395d532d8fc8aae9e69e74a1c2879bbc15a8f95717cf108e9a815693459908  tex.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
787abf8cd9052ad4928db0c9821badcaba4b1398a3e86a4ea696303a2cdd37a7  tex.stackexchange.com.7z
b3f215b0bfbbb813d54d8e6a57718d659a8d5453dd64c9faf55e81a7344fb881  tezos.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
faa89eaf5613b6d4ab8bebd6042b7f48d6ac9b4612e8c5cd037ccb88739ab6fb  tezos.stackexchange.com.7z
c9cd7ac991e6c1fc474671d4de7f9af0af6789419e845e47d51ff427bb48c88d  tor.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c5c428773ca2a7a81904de347fd92183d6aa26bcc97e3a90cf688d8f7a63418b  tor.stackexchange.com.7z
b57eac3a3d2eb30b4feaa795c55cd61adc4364a8165422c6e7dcd4ae2481c26e  travel.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a0d779f2bfad182c14d3a490733ba50a25f28b2460c60454004551c1f30c53c4  travel.stackexchange.com.7z
843e29d8c90761912c45f3fa0955727d85259a8d3e8e0dcd1ef609c8a6458710  tridion.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
37a806d8149a414a787925e68be85ecaee3b8a8f2c600eeb6d7708cbb692a9c6  tridion.stackexchange.com.7z
dabdb2e36e00984356095b42852cdc55c8738094418642e1420e0443235fb87d  ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1cfd4d186e0639bbb5c79d2be6623a5cbf0e1f8881a8434c46390d707be0e014  ukrainian.stackexchange.com.7z
06d69334a246bc57c92247268077873a04b1407089a17a61119f5d20700060f4  unix.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
6fbdff28733bff1608bdda308640565552b6d0f691d52a90427fa596057e9e35  unix.stackexchange.com.7z
0ece83e79a3223a89573ace782e71b191fc1c6fb3d6e3dbda1832ce5cee41b83  ux.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
658e6faf0692ba38598621cc3de49616a72314d48e0e39c7e64e2be0e91053db  ux.stackexchange.com.7z
47eefd491e0ceb0511380017e89de1f836d31491344be858c600737b3244fdcf  vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a1f20ea8a15b4203083d3dff70ea28c9b60cca97631b07794e9ff08294f9d938  vegetarianism.stackexchange.com.7z
010c63f55625747f182bd4a0d19ea1f0fbc4e1afc7e3925feaf53beabd5e49bb  vi.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
febd64c1ce1d817a64a541ec8afb66fe38d15ff15f7059f20dc26b2d7f230546  vi.stackexchange.com.7z
624a2ffe4f0555535155bb530c0e1d5f268db59caf679da37a0121bbd90f965c  webapps.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
caf8421fae938d440ac14ed1d1b69a1eb07517052e5b65b91aafadfd2932dc67  webapps.stackexchange.com.7z
5a1c962ddf66fe7b62eecfabba2fc28400955331d035a31858a44a344d8f8e8d  webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
dba2b4dfa7245b7f6ed4e59f91efe287c41728f11ebdc2356007b931a4088eec  webmasters.stackexchange.com.7z
8fb5748c07ad921b79fb942cb3d55bbf2ec5c28b6cd4ae47d15553b2d409658c  windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
cba2e58bc337a02cc0fd1284d0622681829183c1ca2c9db8f3e935c83cee5d08  windowsphone.stackexchange.com.7z
f12cba6f4512eed4197b4c86f9eb0f67a016a311b7146a888483baad67d26cba  woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
69f580998f1031deef56f90964ed98917391c488740a4d377ef7f62134b19a9d  woodworking.stackexchange.com.7z
a30223467d8351a34013d56a6e4c19acea5b89eab099a0fbe34875a46b3a49ba  wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
de76201c9d32b475181d836c3ea58db56fd2c52c289f1ed8099e2470252092fc  wordpress.stackexchange.com.7z
dc2ec28b4ef749e5a3cfce32a697dbb921ef8a6b582c856ccbd7fc4b32946eed  workplace.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
2215cdd74b658067ebcb7f41741b38d6f2be1a22d8dc976939106cad9715a265  workplace.stackexchange.com.7z
7d4d34d63c33946c45910c94ff82039d69032460c96a22f3b09cfb621131a606  worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
e1fd4de51e84cab504980bdf7bbfe61d9888b2bb57fa0803b083515613837470  worldbuilding.stackexchange.com.7z
59f50e7ebf7b9fa12543e8a03a7fda1da34f43ffcbd91a1499de01271acdb555  writers.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
51020d5d03a7fc10663b838e06a03e9aa941858f9a79595b30a6874a22d75d52  writers.stackexchange.com.7z


2024-Q3
2cf08f0683e8f07e9cf99e3b24c2629fc7ac2653cad37001c0085e0a54ef03dd  3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
2a0fb373e8da94b7cf4654d3812aace39295e03d212651d8cc53bcb5065e49ab  3dprinting.stackexchange.com.7z
8aabfbde0d883556b5035fbc1b90277c1b70412ed85535d24d58bafb996a8429  academia.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
e5b7a86762d495a1944a6c45ed7d448d257cde76c15e62c38a3253cce2d362f0  academia.stackexchange.com.7z
ce82f527885a970efe89961011a4d2d69d7dedcc26dc6bbd463ebd8cf056db03  ai.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
e20307e937ad8302b7ea3bf8588ecd61da90f7986a07b6a8c63b7ae41824504b  ai.stackexchange.com.7z
08df3ea4f04abe7013606452e5292562b68cbcfc3dfa91f3e3ac7f99cbc71ad1  android.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
91675eb69249d8d3f3865126f4e7686f3c1b0e55a501aa7479599e1bf9ff300d  android.stackexchange.com.7z
487b88e48dfea40f544efb47517a19b2c6349cfa28ff5196b6cfa436a5802f72  anime.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f43bb28d251017f58aa67914f4a2fd39b1481834ee5e05dc9d6e6614f24fe3ae  anime.stackexchange.com.7z
1e3db72f304e791e9f8fd97b1f55d22ce176b57bb5e98f809b404a20b2434d31  apple.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ed161a9229f4658ad060128321ffb9e021f9488ca02269788c49d0fdf2af35f2  apple.stackexchange.com.7z
e7730063f87d680f407f42e114dddaa1a418c0eaf3b714c261548d539fc2183f  arduino.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
07132c1367222c963185419bab2e8628d84d031daf48969adb5a4d8814402299  arduino.stackexchange.com.7z
121164fda551ba94c03eeae6227df6f952690a4db9aa504507fe89d98e415643  askubuntu.com.7z
30a751367e142ef5b104273d7d19f9d924659eb1cf4d26d245bf0033b5001b56  astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
cfa6873cec18ed717aed94a0e14d57dcbe108d8e7a9070101d8329ad4e28aefd  astronomy.stackexchange.com.7z
2ef294795bd24384f6ca9eec8ac9c5f3d04d390f5388adcdfd01254bb1c84c4f  aviation.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
7f8e5548ea890c9e2aaeb2f0a8739f8324b07095d43155c6226dbe9be19ddf1c  aviation.stackexchange.com.7z
2220688fa2598957c5f2f50053b64d0a56e0427c14f9806714af314b8e00bc8a  avp.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f5d22458bbb1ef16fc622e06ffd703af57d01311cc90d1d168e1e333514829c9  avp.stackexchange.com.7z
fa217394e06cd291cfe25ec1177eeb36e8e9e3993cdc736b6b8f14c963e936e3  beer.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
5df4db4f4e35c8d785b18f3e9a4f719ce1015e9eb8d04e1f9064f50155a2a82e  beer.stackexchange.com.7z
a1827d06eb5eaa0b3f5e8dfd3eb283fcc24c30a99fadfabd13a1259944fbdc51  bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
604c69fcc40dab4de999382d237074758b7e8c65e31736891ca3c7eea317dbe1  bicycles.stackexchange.com.7z
057544445a01217e29b282cf587b556e2aeeae7e322f3a80adacc9abac015d5b  bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3e13f72e28326117078db970af2ce508a10ad8d88e421cbc914fd6f455111221  bioacoustics.stackexchange.com.7z
8dd6c8224d27c4515ad2ffe79f8109b8757ca9c566e2946b9f89bc3779c38f43  bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a802d4aadd67b311a700c9cac2bf9075d00fca49070522220a24e68cb1d795ff  bioinformatics.stackexchange.com.7z
f62ba2fcbe72589cb215dafefb1cef9dec88ad6a4a9ebee42741113b304f1675  biology.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
afe5a0106c3c6b974a0ccb0876a7f7b6e0aff50cc71179217e2f269581269248  biology.stackexchange.com.7z
3bf88e969ecb88090e5d9960e0b0c9d20fba299f1d614f7ac116a84f2bc0aa45  bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
2766ae8f9cec1599cac1295bf9b3df03ab77c8e6c4302730e3edea28f8852d35  bitcoin.stackexchange.com.7z
3b3ce531a301db7774aa1ce686642569794e8a672e4b868646e73eefc257156d  blender.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
39f7ade3c6cfd0dd15a6a51add4ed612d3061bd1536546a930e629db8781b23c  blender.stackexchange.com.7z
deb55f266d3e50c95fc4b327ac1fc85b47f698790321c10841d3f8c6ce174c77  boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c4c3e83d5921e16727bb65e31220a03eb090ad533c062a6aa616a342af49c5aa  boardgames.stackexchange.com.7z
501fa473fca75bcb4e176b60547b96921509c6a894277432cb11f4c2bb8046dd  bricks.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
fe60c15b161ac056006f487cca3daf29399572914e9b5a0afea59b38f4743f3d  bricks.stackexchange.com.7z
e5214aee77083d3fa783fd1544c66650d810c97fa142f7847c6ec854fa558d46  buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
114c6db45f64fb2857b3ecb15425ba130039206869e5c6c1e48b880c89c71b87  buddhism.stackexchange.com.7z
a031d1de78d6fdc4576df9c31e35d8995e29dc75d8e3e1cf763c6b854c72d317  cardano.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ef689f544ca8ceb0c146b0b1272b6b52334fab8c68273d48f23a56b33ed7765c  cardano.stackexchange.com.7z
28bb200f6aa1079167e4367306fc754d0086439d97ad75b9f580ccb5c9946486  chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
9aeab08fd2f947211d9471cc4c1cec99bfb09e6e36777aa1768189359b2e2a74  chemistry.stackexchange.com.7z
1a8a77b30006ccd2222cfea202ae125055dbf0a43905a4805f73ddeeb52e1484  chess.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d792373d8b60a898046ae09bece8cfc10562696f35b3e08f7ed45aa11ec56cd4  chess.stackexchange.com.7z
2ce64acf693be56844ad63155ef60146275a7c33c061ae5884c2cbd1c1e50931  chinese.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
faaec04fdc50daf6193f328f32dbdcd9f2704a601161435cdd97bd11f3964526  chinese.stackexchange.com.7z
f4a485170023c95f3a185b37ee4370c9e71c4d6ae71387db5b93b60fecbbefab  christianity.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
2f1b234e80bfa443281a73f01bb922f153c70408b2d4f0a205a086cd83a2a498  christianity.stackexchange.com.7z
2e39b769af6db5b99e6fca3998b29cbe357fe5251488215282745942576614d7  civicrm.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f72ed6d1bbc6bc6997213b2c3ef8a2cab5d656d3b0629c3085f839ed61cb0a72  civicrm.stackexchange.com.7z
ed8681db9888d17e24414de23896652d548a555420afdb3b209777df1cffc2a5  codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
01cb61939a18bc03734a98ce14d0a1001123f53f5b5723be18eacc17bd4e3eac  codegolf.stackexchange.com.7z
a453c0dc1a2f6123db0e26f831de12e0becba14ddde71e6ba6aeb8d41d79eb00  codereview.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
867009bef4e444bad2c112915ff6d2304677a23caa65b97c98f1476604d99c56  codereview.stackexchange.com.7z
eb3a88b93439023f8a729eb6e86d72ac4e1fea1102e54cbfcb29622ead4c64d9  coffee.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
5346adffa4cde96061373c94b43773c80c20306647164de5c1fb67abcfce37cc  coffee.stackexchange.com.7z
590aceadf542a925ab118a07948b23e717cf84799dd46b036ab8e96f0ced0c1d  cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f31ec0e4d5ee4c6aa076dd61daea6068df8ac4f566a69cde631cc4e5d29f9052  cogsci.stackexchange.com.7z
89f78cd1c06c816a1df73779492332467ca6a785c5f4f855d1a86eac36af76ee  computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
977cd8ba2a332b09f4ce2e6e1db603f91e1df94863a70a7b486c866715411c49  computergraphics.stackexchange.com.7z
264acec2dcc2d1e4a9cdc7f7f81dda5d557be8a6bebf14374bb0c7026adac9ef  conlang.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
62289c8dfaa598cab0aad8fb5bed45690970729900ceb70f66bec1e7c8f597a8  conlang.stackexchange.com.7z
f505f00fbdb3372d83d007e1886cf8eab7afadc4b13a23be907ebf7f8e989fba  cooking.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f54eb073650460d3527947d8855bf0016827047f365c33fa026386e7c0cf8314  cooking.stackexchange.com.7z
353cbd1281639744ec695ba0a2ba4dbfefc0adf03c5470ed7cbcabdfb7869023  craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1a6b3ea2ec657946dfbcfc79531e524ec5ee9060c8fa5619ec4ba40dee2a845f  craftcms.stackexchange.com.7z
c29cc5d4c780e1b57650398381d2c00a47a8f3f6568427ace09684261d6562ec  crafts.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
cfae4866bb79c9e924d9e51a94028799a07bbbee8da7e6c8d977922367f47f8d  crafts.stackexchange.com.7z
6292c13bd205915f217fb183266827d99b0e452b6b0009dbe08e553d80ebec10  crypto.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4ff6939e38f3bd634a8389f1385e9539f6905249e99c79ff76024f6331233bf6  crypto.stackexchange.com.7z
563329f957ea9f77c27f82180840b82c44ddaa5e14e213366c06e99f74949afc  cs.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
0769b735e10d3dd7852fee8240e5b0ad8eeddd7af6002da8a347a68aacf63785  cs.stackexchange.com.7z
a07978376311d70b3c35f739617d2a5c1703b4eba9574a840614112426e7af0d  cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
822aeca69b7cbfe47f198c21baff1a8acdf3df899eb172121ee142fe33e2a805  cseducators.stackexchange.com.7z
fc1dfec9cde290589855763e3e6f1f8f163bdd875e91fc0b272d22688c4b3820  cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1f2e6146c51818b90eb1fd2f5eaa8f4e5bbc0a2ab540edfdb15a5a8f7ba2174e  cstheory.stackexchange.com.7z
de1561f6390a08cc8abe4319bf58a7b9249ebaaa5f3775c9c2b5d62bfa5f8bdc  datascience.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
bd916ca707fba55d12da1affe3aec0cb6b20d684212393e89fe13b9d7530335f  datascience.stackexchange.com.7z
6b041f82835766021e5f632f17a314c9f1fd314bbdbc8b301e9c3222ab68efab  dba.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
baef8ae0a548469eddd329a87541e1741509eed3607e52d25abab31c963c4515  dba.stackexchange.com.7z
c9015ac247a4312ab9c3f380f3463c2d2bfe591e059a9e20c9dd6b70439976df  devops.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
103bf0077bc664f584a1edad35840b9a53daccb9093cf9c432c1bffccbba1a98  devops.stackexchange.com.7z
d005cd91afbb437f270ba02cb14ee9d20f1667eae31cc4d3f318db76ea8a9196  diy.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
bfd13fee4790301e8cc92b819bfc9c7f02cfea567eeda9b7e2a124932b2b6181  diy.stackexchange.com.7z
6a15223467abf2cd5fd2becb98d0a7a7adfdbbfe0a45de1a7f1ccc91e0f57e64  drones.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
23c7e54a9f88d03abc43a685a7fd3fec02c8f60b99cbe8c9baad643d62007618  drones.stackexchange.com.7z
a0139de755fbb15ae6ca07477180d5b699ca239105d92164a1c53e855fa56232  drupal.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4c9873b5a0ea32b8157a2c7527a42d1072e2229945b2601795f2de9d8950b2db  drupal.stackexchange.com.7z
d4f7a7ac449deb3e7aee62f4e60caae611144618a51110abc7562fa08419270a  dsp.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ff1141574ad088ea80763e437f44f277d40f78dc5f664f079a496dd7c69e771a  dsp.stackexchange.com.7z
a6587db4272672ab4a03844f15b71bcd1d80daa5e78ab042ae07b64464802ed8  earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1da8a1a476c49da4952bab61476613611c4f7eb411f9048dae1b25d55fe0a81c  earthscience.stackexchange.com.7z
db9928dbc6e795abb8cfc257e3a40f7681d239870eb716af1ac6032cb3a42ea1  ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c0e2bdfa2c45cfb6346b276da55ac9b43ccfa1285d2e8d50c3d91ed0a47e85fa  ebooks.stackexchange.com.7z
9223e7e31367f0d4db1389e0f1d647cdb844e50622711f9a86be08e86f8b20bc  economics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f6fd3637cfaad2ee3f73a792ae7cf12cd160c0e65a8365f8a56e6cbd9e2944ee  economics.stackexchange.com.7z
a7706eb9209e74a355fc8d116b519a0ee3cb7b33b788aeb6aa7599d40bc24bff  electronics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4788b17a61ef1b1f7dd00317975076090112ec0349d12551851e2676c4a1d4f9  electronics.stackexchange.com.7z
cb1c2e280c291394dc6f355f4732e775c9dcb68618d1cba61bd9c29515d41527  elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f0bfb4a730bb3ae0307a8aacffee24f419d1ac27c4dcabfdbbdc6d50cf242f04  elementaryos.stackexchange.com.7z
5413221c1440dd82dfc1009d708c5f2401496f35016f7549d8621fd85922c85e  ell.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
88834c3911494dceea3a6a5aa3aae79fd097b3c17b8431ed3230671b0cd79485  ell.stackexchange.com.7z
726907616065a83fb896ae0b84fea9264e15494e2c369575b2f03a1f77571be3  emacs.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ba81133dc848e400340bdb19b2baa644f39f9bc082010f5f6fb94f1f7b03546c  emacs.stackexchange.com.7z
657c6e8b82d790237003440038222e681d2dd5e2460a0a7e27c46dda7e0d2218  engineering.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ba50fd51ef4d8418ccc5619b40e4021020c3e01d938585a1e3bc5ff195d065fe  engineering.stackexchange.com.7z
2e1cf33998f5a44e8fa1f8aaec3602ef0ce96140f0cbbd31b5c71c9021e2e72e  english.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d3f6747e188c808386073e082ebcefc0f6e01cf93805b2ec316c34eeada8c41f  english.stackexchange.com.7z
8ab803f568b287b9206b62dc7244a8843b1e25e06759dfb6e91d4ab571532697  eosio.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
faff0d8b4b3b8b1cd3abea6ee896545695b9b9dc64671b1b899afb8ad0a56692  eosio.stackexchange.com.7z
279528b27bf3bc754bd56d29ba272cc1749e2dcbea50bd5a1c5d5f7ec1439b97  es.meta.stackoverflow.com.7z
ab62bc6b87e28c215afe8afa951a66f7e4bad579cae3d59891b4e2cfcd9eb840  es.stackoverflow.com.7z
da7e2c779c10cb97c694505e0394ffcfc75fb27d8b0f30972b0469da93d68bf9  esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
6ec9da8ffce933dd8059ae2e9b826e1190bd96c7944920ff53ebcb20ab5bf1b8  esperanto.stackexchange.com.7z
39a24b106b23ddf73d7cc332184c63f0a5cb4457a541e3edfa0e38ec617236d7  ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f9d17618cc89b5fa6886620f730bf56dad5e86a71de23ef8517f5226fdf615f0  ethereum.stackexchange.com.7z
8797a8ec279d37dc5a263ef0d17a217ec91191fec7a458ff893bb0d8b7e6525d  expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3bcd763802fcd0b51cc9b187338a8ff48f022c3feab50431f999180b3550e3d0  expatriates.stackexchange.com.7z
2c2864a371b2f221acedc60003bc2b60727728790e701ef0c353f5ebf81a83e3  expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b0e392ecdc113ffe2be96d91527fe5def0c3716ce7d449bc91dc873d866f904a  expressionengine.stackexchange.com.7z
ec42b3f1e57c5d2ffa87fd3e4278d5b491700981216e373af539b00cd52548b9  fitness.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
759db6de9b6b99c78554afa4d98a11ad496246ca8ac265614171e35b2aa38c36  fitness.stackexchange.com.7z
b5f43ca131079e6d340b16b7d09394b8fc6101e46ee732ec6dd4dd32bd361aad  freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3cb439b293c5b47880bd4b22d201c3e4dcc43d62346476c198c68190d1a4b541  freelancing.stackexchange.com.7z
fd9a7f35cff917f384868e31f5dc95c8301dc5c8bc2417942e7afd7c499f50fc  french.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
036fd0d09a710d4f053633c58ee3f9cd4e7e09c049b965fbdb77c2cf66b6ad31  french.stackexchange.com.7z
45bdb25884401926c7857d05eebdc08b30baa73cd357330145cb737f84ab5b5c  gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b9729dc2e28037447ff10a79fced9398f7114e37df6c6e9ef3f8fea8d4c46daf  gamedev.stackexchange.com.7z
e6d440f956dfede6ba755aae982e462ef5b4a0c845449078ecff262803b25895  gaming.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c36e20faf36b3fd506216ed2ce30ba6f886b47f0318e133e2d51c6670e36e6d5  gaming.stackexchange.com.7z
0068d38791815820c156838e97af51811d31822b8b4e9069bb6f1ff10952b7f2  gardening.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
303ef040d4f25eed2930f1f016e73a0f77a7f63da8956b6acd6d06d4be14fcea  gardening.stackexchange.com.7z
e692714f60e07937fec7ef487c4c057397e23e472141741aeb19c724d6f6a4ac  genai.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
7e77b81c6a83ca6107ff988b0ac9f83a7ace3f3aa89de4b662da45563070adac  genai.stackexchange.com.7z
616e76cfbc4096793d9f873b9ab817d50836e51a22f739352835200af06a0c2f  genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ffba4353caa6f8bf4abc0f831a51f26a54e3bcbcf797c4f1e889987ccd211849  genealogy.stackexchange.com.7z
cb7aa7999e23555e34c1a2a253176e5abce8abf4e163b2dc31686a46294a536d  german.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c52a131d51db67c246969abd00288ad21ca021feb485f001dc1d67478cd7abac  german.stackexchange.com.7z
28caf6c51ece44eef779e7281adb13b4b83f1bb0fa568e62f4e30f5a2badc0c4  gis.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
774027223effebe6d3748233705928e7019b9141a785707c4719a788d2d12414  gis.stackexchange.com.7z
96eea92dd4d5cb368e6bb5eb8d907701d064322465528a42623d26a893fdf34d  graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a49e0d8383029dd0068488dba508c0d02901a764d6c3de2dbbb4fb54f19cb2e3  graphicdesign.stackexchange.com.7z
4e031fdb4cc699c2f5f1df002295baa75b1338c8b651cc9969e5c614508621d2  ham.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
cca03bbc7c7579d8278b4da2086c3f4a2c59ce471000fbef11e429547ad35d8c  ham.stackexchange.com.7z
548ab923742437268ca65ead8295389a4c68abf8f0e08fe8390ca37d422bb6d6  hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
992544c60727e385aa7b30e5dfd93ba8dbe39bc211d21645cc56fe0dd20b7830  hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com.7z
5b0a43a370e3ed7d88deb938d3207d16289f584ded817000a6da271df3c2b8ed  health.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
e3aea9ad9d5a38b4d78459baafdd61b3b0d9cfba7281b18b759707c5cdc98565  health.stackexchange.com.7z
135d0823db2ea6e03a277e190f96443ee6fec655024a8ef52e3df7997a3923ec  hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
e1883dd14a2292ff5a3ceb574c518a5b4f6e355f6e9cf58250804717924a4942  hermeneutics.stackexchange.com.7z
e0ef00e012d78a9e2321a514427695c9afb8574e73f1ce6e3fadb71ef4351ebe  hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
efc6723b394e46ebfb6b76949f08c6dc101609087bbbd778e4b4c7c2ff5a929e  hinduism.stackexchange.com.7z
c8e6cbb45bc7623d409401690cca2aa3ebc4747812c2399f6668464f778aaa04  history.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3a23feaf4ff0271fa77855d590bf6f80849c8a339026d553af4a8aa00d5c4840  history.stackexchange.com.7z
c9f24efbc77f02b3dd9d94fe707657ef78c60a50002e93d4166dfdccf4b8beb7  homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
29ecd6531bdc3f98b732f1b8a3d895fca457157aa5326b1a69357b12961a0876  homebrew.stackexchange.com.7z
5d6b71839c206d0c3147abf8f31f05abd19e3214291a188ca005590305c1069b  hsm.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4bbc799fc11068e3bb53de7d6dc9011fe698874f797ce5c7d257abcfd3e98dfb  hsm.stackexchange.com.7z
3d34c632f92fba235ce63ebd19c2ed7fb55266c861910e13bd1e4720c90e8a09  interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
0d68702500dd864c6d52f9675e9508f9e4af1762430ae5a4f618dd9093522e7b  interpersonal.stackexchange.com.7z
e8dae9fb271ef87cf35dce0cb689a61858f8817a53d9f451b974d4cb5c59c550  iot.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
164bb147f2952e4c7321948bb8bb9cd986fac0c51474f4a4c5ede64609a29407  iot.stackexchange.com.7z
eeac9d8de7581c4a0d5df3371c6b3ccb955c02d19d16f0c3e035cb6601cb8940  iota.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
274b79856061de5b88d0be9bb4462fa0c5c53e972168638d044a306da76d3f7a  iota.stackexchange.com.7z
c7532762c671642b0df085e299a7563b1e290b5876f41d199405139627cbe554  islam.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4904ecc7d186761a09e9fa295d97a0662b8ad239ed333a3c84bae6c9c98d60a6  islam.stackexchange.com.7z
53e2ef8ae04c2e8950ab23c4da13ae1e948f8e4c926f6fc0c5f04ff92066ebfd  italian.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4bfcfc4015a8dc2737c2d6d6f3eab84f60dea9cfaac4c15bc61401ce0aa3b5af  italian.stackexchange.com.7z
378ebf33ac8e38395863f6faf14925f441d0e17f35b1c7c4ba08f6943e4d2c43  ja.meta.stackoverflow.com.7z
7f2aca8dd07a352fda1de6fa49e5369d5778ba1053be9a9a95e5c064a32dc70d  ja.stackoverflow.com.7z
dc45d8793356176b35d386a180e13650f24bbb2fb1210b3d617e16232529f594  japanese.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
c630f401b5251e4f11a24c22c2665489b20b22adb37caa0db877aced922a64c1  japanese.stackexchange.com.7z
ec5f1a96b967ab4852ebfde1412d5521e49c2234110d09c541cea79b09c72837  joomla.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ffc2599cf0add01bf26b8acab87e73ca7ac73d8937174ddafc10c26e371b619a  joomla.stackexchange.com.7z
f737ab5fa43b6e8cd166c43191718aad2b01fcbc959f50a350159f30eef6b5fa  judaism.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
9a8b55de4317267715a96bf1c9bd2ff8dd255dcda5906b2e97e737e8e277a78f  judaism.stackexchange.com.7z
bd0e3230ae2c21da3d88c59345a48740ae3e171db5d445d22d0df98591085c71  korean.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a61d8fe0b5986308933c4c8a8632705d56a846564bcbadddd2fbc7609f494368  korean.stackexchange.com.7z
589e648f647909421e7c84f9eae044ebacca9543297237f77e2f68538031e241  langdev.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d95adc9356a0a83cfbdd89fc3468868876da60c07a293d57a7458eee5f319c90  langdev.stackexchange.com.7z
ed25230bf8557ed85f4a5919d2884fa8853e3224f7d143e3a8e89bc94113b94e  languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4a2285957eb1483e6c7afbac2dc529edcbf63f4cde76824ead24ab0bebf2218a  languagelearning.stackexchange.com.7z
5be8f2a0fad8a403a374cfeb38324482982ba86aad25989648973e15b7b27ad4  latin.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
61331eab2ddabe8287e2c9ec383b692629b3489065f6ec6dfb29090546dc24d8  latin.stackexchange.com.7z
4dfe23cb12e8eab73c08a109860dd0cb09c749befd40351b1289d400c718c132  law.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
e1ed73b7305dfc37152a3b0fc412feb8deab3130ab1828867a1435cf7079e5eb  law.stackexchange.com.7z
efbfc06f310f8c6f5667ab63f0ac068dfb9d5aacc833a9dcd6c6d406103b77dc  lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ff9e3ab67d310f22eff079248169022af041201d43b9131e5481a3ab67108840  lifehacks.stackexchange.com.7z
d0a0b2a0171f8a0db378b0a37ea39ad4b393717c8b98bcf07d2079da10a61177  linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
67541bab9f0652eb21b91a6f81d850e12c85c68eee97188be155265fa9f93cd9  linguistics.stackexchange.com.7z
71c0a9221d01e6df2163b0f227b0cd71c68f1108edf95a35cf4ea08920fa6aec  literature.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ac84719823584b87438ca4586e223333038afec99bfe3daaa213390cdb208587  literature.stackexchange.com.7z
bc8435ae0e0203550f95f3497d84fdcc52659beac677ebb0dfd5058f4fdd4de3  magento.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
7fd8819c908a802181c566ddfd605ecb307c2c065528562f77db08188c779af2  magento.stackexchange.com.7z
3b1ece507ba74e6a2354524698b67013f75dddbb5293c6b5bcd47873e94f6eac  martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
e8c164327865af0177d1705a0367a2778ea9b6889acfc2f2951e01af401e9f33  martialarts.stackexchange.com.7z
f1658acbb9017f6392ca403856e7d37f292a0e3ad9f97f1d3d177ac184fdf428  materials.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4bf4984ade8d8db9320cc637a5ed70cca8c102c0319d6dfa0831d66e3ac9045f  materials.stackexchange.com.7z
8f717fc3fc625bbc2ce7008baa571adf8d977f24c5a711964b7511800f0fd991  math.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
267f1eeb8bb03d1c0d763489c5bb665048e5fef8f4b4e28e7e5d5c8491f80a04  math.stackexchange.com.7z
003807b99e1ef99378bbdde7fb89339e5a12a71d64651519fea72681ae7a4777  matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b9e40d45ae8f745d133554b6737d47f879ade5864e4abb2dfda71027ded9f04f  matheducators.stackexchange.com.7z
ae50f7dd5d3d0e548928c7318d4b08adde53772870ec6dead0c2ce9203fd4cbc  mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
8949d0b9da526c8224d1267f0ff253a36d1c140d49b69a5900a6d866ac96ffbe  mathematica.stackexchange.com.7z
8bf270163b0cc561a40497925ab915781d5943bbf85a1380f089e98f23342709  mathoverflow.net.7z
0220fe7e31b6460cf076cec1d0843bbcc51b537b93c9edfe89ed461206810b8e  mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ef2db18e81cc19c67526e82b6bc863d490c656556fed9d60c1a3740f3e6f5153  mechanics.stackexchange.com.7z
756f94e203b402b7c57293a3fe6667935c4bdc634e15e57c02bdab3fe38c6fec  meta.askubuntu.com.7z
2c15f5401b9ed3061f6ee5ddcb26f0adffcd48061c67b864890b4d375bbe8fdc  meta.mathoverflow.net.7z
3c3ee9f48436cc9e519bdfe38bec9e18bd4a61b9b60712c5b73acba5fd877f76  meta.serverfault.com.7z
6dc87b19614280a76e086ebd7b7ee16cfd1af1f0386b28a00e45bd3af1d961e1  meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1712c491630477f79f2d381dda2fd376ceefcaad0a060ce16b86465722e85812  meta.stackoverflow.com.7z
8d55ffb07016386d0bc41307ef5b4bb09f7e246a9cb8fc1acb670655a1ed4d04  meta.superuser.com.7z
f8422b5a563783e9ade20ccdc7b9e3786d6c9d7edc33106d6c77a81d44a71b1e  moderators.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d8d43c078dd1c553be97d8ba710fbe1f3821f22a2e5654b0cf8dad61066b3023  moderators.stackexchange.com.7z
f8c26874e99e170357e6915342b14b46efd8019c70de013d4387ae0d24170498  monero.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
9c1c287c61d1b4b0a889b74fb721031f9ffd72bd755a8e56bd350048e2cb7c07  monero.stackexchange.com.7z
8810507c7e533b544d1c3c3cb3470b2810c55e05b02b88ee7baa7cea2d67a7d0  money.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3660cf7ed9e9814ecb14adb3f78dccb4b484c224b7b71f99bd57c5d0df51fd43  money.stackexchange.com.7z
334e387806370788417147797ba1e1685125d532507f806e81fe6a1d3fc3a288  movies.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
54954c07391e7dd38af17fc2b21fd864adb5fe374f1379c09d13cdf1fff9a7ed  movies.stackexchange.com.7z
7077e15b44139b9bc58129c738139d1f7d6750f68347ce0cebb398f03f3e3289  music.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
7b424cdf2ede8e71ff7911915b514dc904efc7dc04a94ae02a4ee0ab1acde31d  music.stackexchange.com.7z
1c603116ddc4dd6dc720f3fe94b9a88991852e1a3bb9fe120bf315fed562b26f  musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
852a56d8da51bf53e6130f02a216465c86e2dea2cad133c5f68782eb572eac5e  musicfans.stackexchange.com.7z
6bb0946e51f9e742a2495e2baabd8d344f2c8165b1fe423f12b2bb0ed2500758  mythology.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
93ec4cce4a7c94202075642a14c1c2e62854866e12ef66d69053c9b18f345d95  mythology.stackexchange.com.7z
1e1283964c6c3552c50bd086448438d3286c8fd3e5e4c79775aafdeddc31cf33  networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4425d8b1e210062a713cca69aead8769152e84b6595e6163179f114243707dbf  networkengineering.stackexchange.com.7z
e93a496f128f6909620fa0aecea995804587caffa5b29612c8a935d33cbb67f5  opendata.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
7cc8222f325db0a79f534e7a0180eb28d60e730ec6bb218abbac0abbd66e6dff  opendata.stackexchange.com.7z
3c6bb89649bc368e9865aaa45117f2bd47b566119b34a9ebe2e504a84e365ce3  opensource.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4c37794a7fb3d830f6d628c13628a51e91d6e6e9f391d4149111b8be7e237769  opensource.stackexchange.com.7z
b085ac7b90cd2c9e9886245772c09583c67b6d880cb440ed683d23b4c53a9673  or.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
92cb0a2f5be03d113e94a660e64299db956740af74a0469e92dc1a88ea4d09cf  or.stackexchange.com.7z
3679c71474d35e62340133c6710e2dbb0e6078c898c3d666a631da73a8e00cf5  outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
5813d4005ce84a31c3546e7af8ef3cdb78d9e8973085fec296a2f26d8e9216fd  outdoors.stackexchange.com.7z
1b0c1b8846d4afb390f271987b74685f2659e27810bffb82346d43b5ca7e9fbe  parenting.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3a9a506c516ae68b5663b2830bb25c94f571ebd023365042d739f15f47efefa2  parenting.stackexchange.com.7z
abb5203f7e3f969cf5c0ca4502e1f0d8445c95d93584e6222531a499dd0eb108  patents.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d858fc94f2514292dfca50b135aac9658f89bc4ad8da7a212b87fd085573a9a7  patents.stackexchange.com.7z
a25bc70e79ee63a09a9dfcedbb2c7a8fc98cc5bb334a904286bd625477656cd3  pets.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
38a92d27ee00952da0d2eb28a5ab9baaf2f2b90227765079a9586f74b9edec8e  pets.stackexchange.com.7z
19331f15515621bb1da5921b122d320fc37d397070a33a624619b9f1b1344955  philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b4d75259c054e76ddb74d7d3c261c96b1660c449203d6aec56818c1031bc651b  philosophy.stackexchange.com.7z
5bc3af80a2d424ccb9e968e54129597e65f99db468430b7a5c3d2f6c7099e148  photo.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
294bc3fc2f0053adc15d68873bbf4806dcab557f6c6b9be403fac39e1bd28250  photo.stackexchange.com.7z
a46eaaf32a2632ac2c54abdcdcfb786bdf4cba3ef8fead32b95aa7afbd2fad8a  physics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
36b3d6e3e0978fd7e57558d2d633ad3448715d5a699186aac5e0567b44a37b05  physics.stackexchange.com.7z
5234c92e1b4aabfd997a1fb240a66eca5c21aa3d8bf5f6223445c4ae021e462c  pm.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
28173d3d9788da3996ff90122d48d8df747178d886022f98bde6a5ddc36d84a8  pm.stackexchange.com.7z
913e6e9c5402dbd6e372e8f820728356d1fa79b3504b7a32256d0a8da1635c30  poker.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
9e17ebea50f4c1fd8b105c853c778a4e6ba68d9295e4d82a40799820ae83dff4  poker.stackexchange.com.7z
08ac7b2d115bf7ed6fa6802463dd5f22e2a60fb8b9eff030f75e83b23a2b34af  politics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4790c034f618c7cb320df13151b8a6d66fdaff713d56c436276f29b88267a180  politics.stackexchange.com.7z
a798c232959e881d74350ed8928191e1045a564d4639746d33e9e6317b2fd018  portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
66ef53add1bb6051e53abe0ea8fc57b4a92fc0a9d47cbbb3cb849ccb5eb4dabd  portuguese.stackexchange.com.7z
ab4c6a253355635963e0529847f5a4c7f2e38f6df7e3e40b3381d021660b6956  proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d4f40403a1d23af490d6378ad9de0a15255129b622555f2d070dccb7acbe01c6  proofassistants.stackexchange.com.7z
ae085fd7e961b3b3b374047b1a041ecdca8cc96527fee300604f9a0decc4fa3d  pt.meta.stackoverflow.com.7z
bf2adf1b03756625a7df5972005bda1ae2ecf32af45c725d974f32f3977d4437  pt.stackoverflow.com.7z
8d5533f9089d538c757ce59696e2602c4b5305cf1385fc57ee6a0cd07043d2b1  puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
cfed746f0b5e4cbe8c6d58205f8769849695563cf47ec370d150a607864e3e46  puzzling.stackexchange.com.7z
778002df412268f29fde381825140be704e59df33716500effa02011fb204e59  quant.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4aeef3dce140b3c797015e4425326c5e4f689ea66a84434a9fefebc07eff8991  quant.stackexchange.com.7z
ea1d692365630914de50706f4c7eb901c880bbc89d989a968005ad84b14c131c  quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
0d17ae05672b9a54f01a9b0100601dff5e80a9aab61390f8c4d6c3d5fc3eb719  quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com.7z
befc7164ef3bb5af887a283ce3b513cf5f15f1d0d94014cbdafac45bbaee448f  raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
df56f75a08ecde06c15e1fe7fa37fa47ed1cbf1e7e0e26e835b1d5af0d87ffe6  raspberrypi.stackexchange.com.7z
e6c95ba680f73b7e0bc0f7a7c02de6134a6e6ab8ae23679a576f6bb5f205110d  retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3b4547402bbe7c7fe6c99d83aaa9a71b3b3bc2c9bbfde751b16e967477a0b86d  retrocomputing.stackexchange.com.7z
da5faeb9f2c7673250cbcf30bf2bcad54d0c462cf77cefdbaecd98ae3999f8cc  reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
637105fedf2ccd7b820ac00571d8b7a2c84f8d685bc6b714ab92cfe20dfef5f7  reverseengineering.stackexchange.com.7z
6ecb4af375ce056a1ee03df5df60b77bc67c68f04bf92e725016d9e4b1961a38  robotics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
65ec7aadfba31a1b484f9d9a2d80f18bc8ceb8beb7884322041ba71ba6ff3939  robotics.stackexchange.com.7z
f64a8aed4ba3e851780583b356a960c0549564eb3dfe7268adcb5dd4c5e57fae  rpg.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d236d72ef5d9878042f442b1e5628a1dcfa49c25fd8d6e2a606572db88e95630  rpg.stackexchange.com.7z
d2067c885975702c29d21f16aa958330ad7cdad238a97569a03d5d6f61b0f3db  ru.meta.stackoverflow.com.7z
b7409bdd45daf712859388133463fe0b9a59664b77557cbb5ee7ca086eaeab67  ru.stackoverflow.com.7z
cd3d3471e3afbabd4b66cb06d81e7c28b665b9378f904707194f155a8d0f1e9c  rus.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a9257563c82ca317b3ea09132120e8e3512bbb98d59da9617c5f1e0b48185108  rus.stackexchange.com.7z
21fe15af2da55515fbb4e06b815316a9b1034f8cf37898fdf8bfdf30165dc7c6  russian.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
fc2b8ae2445272d1cdc6f80ac0eac662952982c52044acde4bf674ca19a8e7ae  russian.stackexchange.com.7z
4eef14426c0a18cc3b6cec84f564a68dc747c77bd38ccd15495bacdc40e109b8  salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b8a814c3915a8b0fcf9ea548e73645a76990725e5ce27f1d5b7dd803bc276eb8  salesforce.stackexchange.com.7z
ec2716f17db59fb9a30c4b26a2014de1f7cb988e6639cbe7ba9780c6ad0bb78e  scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f8dcb2ba9f81fc510580d8750f9ffa0f43940b28252659010da484d753d04cfb  scicomp.stackexchange.com.7z
fb4f97f6a8124b8be25c13b9d5c582d81992a108115bd15fa1c28aa50f783079  scifi.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
8ac4d1887979246977f8a52a989e8cce658c0f9a3615a8d49d948378c080e130  scifi.stackexchange.com.7z
2bf05623a9f86b5461d18cad4ddd35fb2b71bbaa34e40496c234c8601d4894ea  security.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f484c6da2d89d9ff58ccc9ea43a0b34d3576eb309a5979e4689ff606e7399883  security.stackexchange.com.7z
5ebb58983912d8e6f002a5b4e8d47087264b3e5dcefc89de25c6701893c86610  serverfault.com.7z
ee2292944c965da6ef88f9ad31a79c785dc3af6ea6aca29c9feb8efa3971e11e  sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
8065bdb91882b3b37fe72860e15422fbda94c2dad6dfcf48ce0ef76bb1efd68e  sharepoint.stackexchange.com.7z
4c2183701728d565fd8479a1d8c6a6e2d69d8c9e3d7b3e0dcc71cd84070db375  sitecore.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
42e6b8c4494c0a9d8a934b0d823c4ca975838bf412c1974d1366d86dbf14a488  sitecore.stackexchange.com.7z
618f23ddf55c38c6122adc94c5a452386d1533cf8344ebfdc2e7e560e71224ea  skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
4264a20125a7991ad632286c1e364b94d7bb45327b7f18b02a274a7e3a35d894  skeptics.stackexchange.com.7z
ffa130c1635a8c542c7a8012596e766ca8273c12165179e933bb260c719d8478  softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
1ef872a49c272417f56165457a9e408036b7c73917853eecaa3be7bfc1409d0c  softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.7z
dde5eafc2aacda7d1beb993822213731f02b7fdce335f17c302a6d9b9d0d5e20  softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
ecd636e6b401b3c319cf61ea31c29e94ce6b8f1f10eafc3f8ea2629b47696b81  softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.7z
de5ff447a9aaf548991665bd80f017001a2e67614047ceb9ddd8627533b11e1a  solana.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
fdea4474141d6ffe4f74211def5fc2c41a4119ae516c9e2b7f1e9faf2c12c865  solana.stackexchange.com.7z
953182cfd78c589966611f67168ec666bb6e06f5e6a21b6d31393dd0ae2d789c  sound.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
42691fedf7378442b986d4ed9f4a6d138cc9a931e42cc722dd72003c6f2c12f7  sound.stackexchange.com.7z
2efd41c34d83f52402f466964f99cbc12ce247058be5dd40b075d37de7b00317  space.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
02525ce069b456e2803735e61ff92c66b40946c0f739f47a21098c3b26b17fd8  space.stackexchange.com.7z
badea1c0ee81a6d1c7c081e2c49d3e6ab45d63e86a49cc29ceb0aba557773934  spanish.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
22f684f410bcdf8ebd4ec79b1ee3c9e563edb8f71dbfea79c80e189c22274a7e  spanish.stackexchange.com.7z
2557f07a58ae48ddc0ebcbcf1ff0ba3183114d53093dcf475fe756bb9834cf59  sports.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
6dfd0fe4cdfc303179fa10f781a83f818c2418dfd4ff1e77f77c48411a30ce0f  sports.stackexchange.com.7z
cbbfa18d54dc9175dcfb3ef93d5963340e36b11665c987ec62c2ee4f4ed14c0b  sqa.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
459bf7dd796298e274eec7a7d21c8f20b13ee63f7e5db7e67d305277c2359c5a  sqa.stackexchange.com.7z
e76303da8af4e16cf77432267eebcc9ef4f0b00483a804fe95ff8d74fa6c8344  stackapps.com.7z
3d654691883b5b185e9a5a897e31f32aaad77b3fe4a91f0b9f36e6327531bac7  stackoverflow.com.7z
f4882259b7a449685cb4947c0c82f825e4230496254afd62c5bad3160af8b354  stats.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
37a05bfdd997cd1be080ebff25987a2fd1276152448220cb2c22fb9c8694179a  stats.stackexchange.com.7z
446ac6065cc0928d8c71cf279da67ecef93fb77ce6c77325be9eaff2ca1d6a23  stellar.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
f90d34be7c616fedf666e48779ac04d8a07efae1eafc138f3ca3efcba5c7522b  stellar.stackexchange.com.7z
a1798d6bd3e1cc415b00b3a98193b54c4aaf8667b15747db234d6dc71ca2d24c  substrate.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
68675602eb0a81c8fb966432fa336919124802025974f7e923e6dee2c8eb5b27  substrate.stackexchange.com.7z
d8ab8deae74da25d9d81c62679939a43e70af257714bf9fde40ef43a92efebd7  superuser.com.7z
f2ad5c61ef29189139fecfed830268ffbe8ba2c07baa15e02551199f99d95539  sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
0a5f9c3645b49bebbbf140d9c8f738cd2a6559dde40a63645e69fc6788db54b8  sustainability.stackexchange.com.7z
28d557f20168ad14bea4ccd73bb058904fc585818be35011964727cfa51523f1  tex.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
2023552bb6ce6798d9ef71067dc61f6e6001303d21be84397ba64f67ac411f58  tex.stackexchange.com.7z
fa900e34e5fc20f0ed3b952b4017d4ffd044c933a4daf638ea930cb8bb841d89  tezos.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
01999af643f60f1af71c88b48829155155d4d82ce44545d5aafe34863c98ccf4  tezos.stackexchange.com.7z
c7bb05fd871cb4ab5a64a8e871be5ca7004f2e3447f2932baa383c8c156b5a73  tor.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
d533383707c6043ddf95757bdd1f1160cbf6235254049b2593e3403f061a661e  tor.stackexchange.com.7z
8da0d0c97239b5d2d80f0146039aece51a79a134f7119b265fa8ca767408e6cd  travel.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3fd65f03f5b94805122dcc2c1ceb044728b3dee9e2bd9e000b5dc310be2c8ab6  travel.stackexchange.com.7z
16249f018772924fdae80622a4c99e3ae7494e43d87f92a8bcac9a1fa4b7fbff  tridion.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
9f7df90837016ee2c119453cf5787b088718e14e86946fb4582b058cfdb0ffb8  tridion.stackexchange.com.7z
46a650eda14ee13b578582113d66684422cb4912dec3b54256730b27abd9988b  ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b951874f0bb6857da1bbdc764b4b8d2cc68518a6d20efab8ac505ec1165f668c  ukrainian.stackexchange.com.7z
c74fc677ac6ea2ec730cc937e0c58c95817b00de8c2977a479505bf57f4d7242  unix.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
09489f315093399104932fc31ec18748c0774549b5e7c03381015460180f833f  unix.stackexchange.com.7z
cc70eb05c0d84a6d11d97b059ad7a8a1825fcd8be5d3da3a6740c2a502e3c9fb  ux.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
5de75fcfff367a6b6c25bd2b2c2eba8cfd7922055dbea80e6569bb9d3a990cba  ux.stackexchange.com.7z
5e4b3c5e653766d6411cc1e349d0d7a15a8e3bbcb1a6b18299fdf45d930571ef  vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
a42f1d555df56fcae3f2850df7cf5769fa3eea08ad6c6764c85c6d3c4508e023  vegetarianism.stackexchange.com.7z
de446e0e8125511b0fa140aa8df90b23413d718945c8f62a6582d0e95a0d87dc  vi.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
025418a4cdbb41ab99a84c30064a1245205b683015d1218b91199ddec1396e1a  vi.stackexchange.com.7z
6c78383b31041165b223efec16a0f8c81689bec43ea9d3ea78ed4297c8596c2b  webapps.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
b321bd5348c99996e190e36423ac9288e88a499c912bedfd151ecd2ef80e7e46  webapps.stackexchange.com.7z
44b81c20fbd08ce11acc1d2695bd9d56b3f94be37420fdeee1a8595be980a990  webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
cd96c8380bc2f3d3e92219446419ef98d5193899af04630d990a4f1bdb262592  webmasters.stackexchange.com.7z
ec788c419e4d4fe1f57ef227a92105496624ac9d918464d4966f8bf7806b489e  windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
fc114dd34298f4ae31bdc8b228ec85e9017501f2f6c377e0270cce801067546b  windowsphone.stackexchange.com.7z
ae9dbc0a45667bd138b76fa429160132fd07907c86041268126fc4e841fcdc9c  woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
3b386b53ed3bd0808f47848f14f38421cc1e51d6337138d586ff1e3ed11f4918  woodworking.stackexchange.com.7z
05d77df7c440e63dc43ca03adf4c0bf250d7f54fbea9cae4649c5759faf82d98  wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
89ebacc5506eeca9a30036aa087f685f349e17eccd5b9d2d8b8d8edc12920bc2  wordpress.stackexchange.com.7z
083288584d409daeb95c35c2972cf8d96bb93f874464338a4fae6cf6e0b18ad0  workplace.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
0b3d427c25675f8dca90e8a9e4fa7572387aea8c5b9864f0fe6447fa256bb00d  workplace.stackexchange.com.7z
2fab0d86832a58265dde3bd052e2efc2f95d0da9a7dae051fdb7def906ce42fe  worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
256891852dfe53884f984184d65ca3de12febff42d004b77c40718c7decbe5cd  worldbuilding.stackexchange.com.7z
64f3dca530f6a500287ac0f06843e342cf79437ac000ff74d7bb5a26e5302883  writers.meta.stackexchange.com.7z
58c9956d6d620ba7e75a3ca7496e50083446e373a6b284cbeb81c173d9f6e0b3  writers.stackexchange.com.7z

